# Does LDAP (or any Ruby client library for LDAP) support batch calls?

Tags: ruby, ldap

I'm thinking no, but hope to be corrected.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol

i.e. i'm simply looking to a batch read of ~1000 users via one query, instead of making ~1000 separate queries.

Update:
Okay, it helps to read the spec:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2254

: )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why batch?

```
(|(cn=user1)(cn=user2)(cn=user3)(cn=user4)(cn=user5)(cn=user6))
```

The LDAP filter string length can be looked at as unlimited for nearly all practical purposes.

Comment: Maybe you can specify a bit more what you're after? :)

Comment: I'm ultimately trying to do a query that starts from a given employee, then walks up their management change, stopping based on an employee's grade level (and returning that high-level manager).  There's probably no way to do that within a single query, though.

Comment: Pay attention to the filter escaping rules in section 4! Don't put in any unescaped values when building your filter string.

Comment: If you are walking the the manager hierarchy, my answer to a question asked much earlier (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190516) may be of value to you. It's not ruby, but the general approach is probably useful all the same.