# Active Directory search - filter by Manager

Tags: c#, active-directory, filter, ldap

I'm trying to get a list of users from the Active Directory, who have a specified manager.
I used the following LDAP filter without success:

```
(manager=CN=Misterboss_n*)
```

However, it returns no result. Users have the following value in the manager attribute:

```
"CN=Misterboss_n,OU=xyz user,DC=xyz,DC=local"
```

What am I doing wrong? If I replace the above filter with something like this:

```
(givenName=John*)
```

it works okay (returns all users whose given name is John).

Wider context:

```
public List<ADUserDetail> GetAllEmployeesUnderMisterboss()
        {
            List<ADUserDetail> userlist = new List<ADUserDetail>();
            string filter = "";
            _directoryEntry = null;
            DirectorySearcher directorySearch = new DirectorySearcher(SearchRoot);
            directorySearch.Asynchronous = true;
            directorySearch.CacheResults = true;
            filter = "(manager=CN=Misterboss_n*)";
            directorySearch.Filter = filter;
            SearchResultCollection userCollection = directorySearch.FindAll();
            foreach (SearchResult users in userCollection)
            {
                DirectoryEntry userEntry = new DirectoryEntry(users.Path, LDAPUser, LDAPPassword);
                ADUserDetail userInfo = ADUserDetail.GetUser(userEntry);
                userlist.Add(userInfo);
            }
            return userlist;
        }
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a start-of-field search available for DN-typed properties. You will have to use the full DN of the manager. If you don't know the full DN, find the manager's LDAP object first and use its `distinguishedName` property.

Be sure to [escape the DN value properly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475.aspx) before building your filter - not every character that is valid in a DN is also valid in an LDAP filter expression:

```
*   as  \2a
(   as  \28
)   as  \29
\   as  \5c
NUL as  \00
/   as  \2f
```

For code samples, see this related thread where I answered a very similar question: [Getting all direct Reports from Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190516/getting-all-direct-reports-from-active-directory)

Comment: Thank you, escaping the DN solved my query; I was wondering why the full DN did not work