# ldap filter for distinguishedName

Tags: php, ldap, ldap-query

I am successfully querying our Active Directory for a  user with the following code:

```
$filter = (&(objectCategory=person)(samaccountname=someusername));
$fields = array("samaccountname","mail","manager","department","displayname","objectGUID");

$user = ldap_search($ldapconnection, $baseDn, $filter, $fields);
```

The resulting array gives this value for the `manager` attribute:

```
CN=McBossy\, Boss,OU=Users,OU=CentralOffice,DC=ds,DC=example,DC=com
```

This looks like a distinguishedName to me. But when I try to query for the manager's record,

```
$filter = (&(objectCategory=person)(dn='CN=McBossy\, Boss,OU=Users,OU=CentralOffice,DC=ds,DC=example,DC=com'));

$manager = ldap_search($ldapconnection, $baseDn, $filter, $fields);
```

the query fails with `PHP Warning:  ldap_search(): Search: Bad search filter`

I've tried a number of possibilities including different quotation, more parentheses, using `distinguishedName` rather than `dn`, etc.

What am I doing wrong and what is the right way to get the manager's record?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`dn` is not an attribute. Only attribute types, OIDs, and names can be used in filters.

When you get the `manager` attribute, to get the attributes for the DN that is the manager, use the value of the `manager` attribute as the base object in a search request. Set the scope of the search to `BASE`, the filter to either `(&)` or `(objectClass=*)` and request the attributes required. Then transmit the search request to the server and interpret the response.

Comment: ok. Then, given that the only link to a user's manager (so far as I know) is the `manager` attribute, how do I use that information to get the manager's user record?

Comment: Wouldn't that find all the people who had my current user as a manager? I want to get the manager of my current user. Sorry if I'm being thick.

Comment: Yes, it would. I re-read your question and updated my answer.

Comment: Hi, I'm in the same boat -- I can query a user by email, get their manager in the result, then I want to get their manager's manager, but all I have to work with from the first AD result is "CN=McBossy\, Boss,OU=Users,OU=CentralOffice,DC=ds,DC=example,DC=com". I don't know enough about AD to make use of this answer. I understand when you say that you can't search by DN, but how do I "set the scope of the search to BASE"? I'm using almost the same code as @dnagirl to start.

Comment: @BrianAshe, php's ldap_search is a wrapper for ldapsearch. To understand the options, have a look here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Directory_Server/8.2/html/Administration_Guide/Finding_Directory_Entries-Using_ldapsearch.html You're probably most interested in the `-b` option

Comment: The full DN in the search filter did not work for me until I escaped special characters (in my case parenthesis) - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827263/active-directory-search-filter-by-manager

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but I don't think it was answered clearly. You can search AD by DN for a user, computer, or group, but it must be escaped properly, so use the built in function.

```
$ldap_to_find = ldap_escape($manager_dn, "", LDAP_ESCAPE_FILTER);
$ldap_filter  = "(distinguishedName={$ldap_to_find})";
```

From my testing, adding class or category to the filter makes no speed difference, probably because DN is the location and not an attribute.  Adding them would just be to enforce object type at the search level.

Comment: Quick note for anyone finding this answer, which helped me out: passing NULL as the second parameter is now deprecated (haven't been able to find a specific version where it started, but at least as early as 8.1); so pass an empty string instead. Here's the link to the `ldap_escape` documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-escape.php

Answer (score 2):

If there is an entry in LDAP

```
dn: uid=John Smith,ou=people,dc=example,dc=org
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
cn: John Smith
sn: smith
uid: jsmith
uid: John Smith
mail: j.smith@example.com
ou: accounting
```

and if you want to search entries whose `dn` contain `uid=John Smith`, the command will look like:

```
ldapsearch  -b dc=example,dc=org -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org"  -LLL '(uid:dn:=John Smith)'
```

See https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/how-to-write-ldap-search-filters-792496933.html for a reference.