# Search users reporting to the same manager in LDAP

Tags: java, ldap

I am trying to query LDAP from Java, to get all users reporting to the same manager.

When I query using the searchFilter as - `String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" + search + "))";`

I get the the output as `manager=CN=Eve\, Adam,OU=something,OU=something,OU=StandardUser,OU=User,DC=something,DC=something,DC=something`

However when my search query is `String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(manager=CN=Eve*,OU=StandardUser,OU=User,DC=something,DC=something,DC=something))";`

OR

with `String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(manager=CN=Eve*))";`

I do not get an output.

Following is the way I am trying to fetch the data.

```
String searchBase = "DC=something,DC=something,DC=something";
String returnedAtts[] = {"*"};
SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();
searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts);
NamingEnumeration answer = ctxGC.search(searchBase, searchFilter, searchCtls);
```

Please note - 
`DC=something` definitely has some value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client is attempting to use a substring filter with a DN (`(manager=CN=Eve*)`). There is no substring matching rule for DN, therefore, substring filters cannot be used with DNs. When specifying a DN in a search filter or as the base object in a search request, the LDAP client must use the full DN, for example, `cn=user,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com`.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Mastering Search Filters](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/mastering-ldap-search-filters.html)
- [LDAP: Search best practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)
- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)

Comment: Thank you, however, even with `String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(manager=CN=Eve\\, Adam))";` I do not get any output.

Comment: `manager` has DN syntax, therefore, the client must use the full DN, not just a portion of it.

Comment: I tried `String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(manager=CN=Eve\\, Adam,OU=StandardUser,OU=User,DC=something,DC=something,DC=something))";` and still no output.

Comment: Check that the `cn=eve\\, Adam` part is correct (spaces, etc).

Comment: The full DN in the search filter did not work for me until I escaped special characters (in my case parenthesis) - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827263/active-directory-search-filter-by-manager