# Remoting: fill the collection on remote side

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

I have simple remoting API that has method similar to this:

```
bool FillMyList(List<string> ListToFill)
{
    ListToFill.Add("something");
    ListToFill.Add("more stuff");
}
```

But, when I call it through a proxy object, upon return, ListToFill stays as it was (in my case, empty).

What now?  I must point out that rest of my methods are called fine - they pass parameters in one direction and have return value for the other.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838117/ref-keyword-and-appdomains) any help?

Comment: It seems like it could be - let's try ref first...

Comment: ref doesn't work - why should it...  I moved my List to be a return value and it works now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you typically get back from Remoting calls is the return value; the parameters are not marshalled across, usually. Marking the parameter `ref` probably won't help, but it may depend on how you are doing the remoting. Having the function return the list itself instead of the `bool` or a custom object that includes both, should solve it.

Comment: Yes, it seems like no-one knows how to force marshaller to pass object to and FROM the remote side...  Possible?