# refactor accessing child controls in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Better way to find control in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955769/better-way-to-find-control-in-asp-net)

Hi,

Is there any way to refactor this:

```
placeholder1.Controls[0].Controls[0].Controls[0].Controls[0].Controls[1].Controls[1].Controls[1].ClientID.ToString();
```

Thanks

Comment: Some more detail as to what you are doing would be helpful - this seems like a horrible way to get the ClientID

Answer (score 0):

Are those controls created dynamically?  If not, you can just specify the control you want by whatever you named it.  `WhatYouNamedIt.ClientID.ToString()`