# Page.FindControl comes back null for DIV

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have a page where I create div controls dynamiclly and number them automaticlly.

```
subCell = new TableCell();
subCell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(
    "<div id=\"picker" + Index.ToString() + "\" runat=\"server\" 
     class=\"colorSelector\"><div style=\"background-color: #000000;\">Text
     </div></div>"));
subRow.Cells.Add(subCell);
subTb.Rows.Add(subRow);
```

Later in the code I want to get the background-color value like so:

```
HtmlGenericControl div;

div = (HtmlGenericControl)Page.FindControl("picker" + e.CommandArgument.ToString());

string colorCode = div.Style["background-color"].ToString();
```

after these line of code I get a null object ref error.
div is null.
I have tried HtmlControl and LiteralControl as the object type and that does not help either.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Page.FindControl only works for server controls.  You are assigning an id to text within the literal control which happens to be a div, but not the control itself.  If you set the id of the control you should be able to find it, but I don't know if that's what you're intending.

In response to your comment, check your HTML.  The runat=server will probably be there because ASP.NET isn't processing it as a control, it is treating it as content.  Try something like this, noting that Page.FindControl only works on immediate children.  Here I've declared a server panel named 'declaredPanel' in the aspx.  ClientIdMode.Static makes it so ASP.NET won't add parent names to the control (like "MainContent_childPanel")

```
<asp:Panel ID="declaredPanel" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

In Page_Load:

```
    Panel p = new Panel();
    p.Style["background-color"] = "#aaeeaa";
    p.ID = "childPanel";
    p.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static;
    p.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div id=\"div111\" runat=\"server\">Hello, world!</div>"));
    declaredPanel.Controls.Add(p);
    Panel p2 = declaredPanel.FindControl("childPanel") as Panel;
    string colorCode = p2.Style["background-color"]; // reports "#aaeeaa"
```

Produces this:

```
<div id="declaredPanel">
    <div id="childPanel" style="background-color:#aaeeaa;">
        <div id="div111" runat="server">Hello, world!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But doesn't adding runat="server" make it a server control? Can I just access the control directly?

Comment: +1. Also div is not a control, and it is not posted to server.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add dynamic controls in OnInit event and event at postback. If not - all controls will be not visible at postback
[HOW TO: Dynamically Create Controls in ASP.NET by Using Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317794)

> Note When you create dynamic controls
> on a Web Form, the controls must be
> created and added to the controls
> collection either in the OnInit or in
> the Page_Load events. Otherwise, the
> controls behave unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Panel instead of a LiteralControl. It'll be rendered as a DIV and will be found by `FindControl` via it's ID. You can't find the div because it is "wrapped" inside the LiteralControl. [Control.FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) searches the current [NamingContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx) for a control(`runat=server`) with the given ID. Remember that `FindControl` won't find elements recursively(f.e. in all TableCells on a page).

Have a look here for a ... [Better way to find control in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955769/better-way-to-find-control-in-asp-net/4955836#4955836)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
LiteralControl literalControl = new LiteralControl();
literalControl.ID = "divLiteralControl";
literalControl.Text = ...
subCell.Controls.Add(literalControl);
```

Then use the FindControl method to get the literal control and edit its text.

```
LiteralControl literalControl = 
    (LiteralControl) subCell.FindControl("divLiteralControl");
literalControl.Text = ...
```