# ASP.net FindControl return null

Tags: asp.net, panel, code-behind, findcontrol

I have code like this

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
            Table t = new Table() ;
            t.ID = "T1";
            t.Visible = true;
            MyPanel.Controls.Add(t);
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
            Table t = (Table)MyPanel.FindControl("T1");
}
```

I have problem there: `Table t = (Table)MyPanel.FindControl("T1");`

In variable t, there is now reference to null. I looks like the aplication doesn't know about code-behind generated
table. Do I have to "Register" the table somewhere else than only to the MyPanel? Thank you for the answers.

**EDIT**
More information about the problem

I have simple page without masterPage.There is Gridview with a numbers. This numbers mean how many rows and cells the new TAble will have. When the user select a row, I want to create appropriate Table and after click on second button I need collect information from the table. OnInit or PreRender I don't know, how much rows I will need. Does it mean my problem is technically impossible?

Comment: first of all you are adding a table to Panel1 and finding it in MyPanel. How will you find the table?

Comment: Just in case your sample isn't a complete representation, note that `FindControl` searches only children 1 level deep - you may need to recurse to find deeper child controls - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589950/findcontrol-return-null

Comment: But I know here exactly, what is parent and child, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Panel1 but you are searching a table called MyPanel ??

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            Table t = (Table)Panel1.FindControl("T1");
}
```

This should get you the table

**EDIT**

Ok I dug up some old webForms stuff that does exacly this.

BUT you have to add your table on the initialize or preInit event of the page, if you want to interact with it in code later. And you have to **Recreate** the conrol on each postback.

```
public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id)
{
    if (root.id == id)
        return root;
    foreach (Control ctrl in root.Controls)
    {
        Control FoundCtl = FindControlRecursive(ctrl, id);
       if (FoundCtl != null)
            return FoundCtl;
    }
    return null;
}
```

And you can use it lik this.

```
table myTable = FindControlRecursive(this.Master, "T1") as Table
```

Comment: Are you using master pages? And are the button1 and button2 in the same page/cs file ?

Comment: I have simple page without masterPage.There is Gridview with a numbers. This numbers mean how many rows and cells the new TAble will have. When the user select a row, I want to create  
appropriate Table and after click on second button I need collect information from the table. OnInit or PreRender I don't know, how much rows I will need. Does it mean my problem is technically impossible?

Comment: It is absolutely possible. You just have to do some manual stuff. You just have to acept that the hardcoded onClick stuff won't work, but you can check in the Initialize event for the Id of the control who did the postback (String ButtonID = Request["__EVENTTARGET"];) and then render the table and after rendering the table you know the information and can build your detail view or whatever you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

do your code OnPreRender

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
            Table t = new Table() ;
            t.ID = "T1";
            t.Visible = true;
            MyPanel.Controls.Add(t);
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$UrunlerRAjax1$rptCustomers

contentplaceholder-->usercontrol-->repeater

```
Repeater rptCustomers = this.Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("UrunlerRAjax1").FindControl("rptCustomers") as Repeater;
```

Repeater rptCustomers = this.Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("UrunlerRAjax1").FindControl("rptCustomers") as Repeater;

Repeater repeaterName = this.Page.Master.FindControl("ContentName").FindControl("UsercontrolName").FindControl("repeaterName") as Repeater;

Comment: This is not a social network to greet people! Please format your answers based on the guidelines and provide proper, high quality details for an answer you want to write.