# ASP.NET NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net, exception

I am trying to write the user login details to the Database.
When I click the submit button Im getting a NullReferenceException.
There are 4 TextBoxes
Username, Email, Password and ConfirmPassword.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((RegisterUserWizardStep.FindControl("Password") as TextBox).Text == (RegisterUserWizardStep.FindControl("ConfirmPassword") as TextBox).Text)
           {
                //call the method to execute insert to the database
                ExecuteInsert((RegisterUserWizardStep.FindControl("UserName") as TextBox).Text,
                              (RegisterUserWizardStep.FindControl("Email") as TextBox).Text,
                             (RegisterUserWizardStep.FindControl("Password") as TextBox).Text);
                Response.Write("Record was successfully added!");
                ClearControls(Page);
          }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Password did not match");
                (RegisterUserWizardStep.FindControl("Password") as TextBox).Focus();
           }
        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Which line does the exception occur on?

Comment: And when you break on the exception which values that it is using are null? Answer these questions and you have pretty much solved your problem. ;-)

Comment: Also, just to check. In your description you've said that you have a `Username` TextBox. The code is looking for `RegisterUserWizardStep.FindControl("UserName")`. Is this a typo in the question?

Comment: hello..previoulsy i used the if statement if(Passord.Text==ConfirmPassword.Text). But i got an error saying The name "Password" is not in the current context. So i used the function Find Control(). And now I put a breakpoint on the if Statement and all the field seem to have the values that i have inserted. so nothin is null.

Comment: Hello...and my textBox is "UserName"  and not Username. Sorry..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its likely that FindControl didn't find the control you are after, possibly because the TextBoxes are [nested under another child control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955769/better-way-to-find-control-in-asp-net) like a panel etc.

Instead of

```
if ((RegisterUserWizardStep.FindControl("Password") as TextBox).Text
```

try

```
TextBox passwordTextBox = RegisterUserWizardStep.FindControl("Password") as TextBox;
// .. same for username and email
if ((passwordTextBox != null) && (usernameTextBox != null) ... )
{
 // Do something with the textboxes
}
// else you have a bug
```

This will also prevent you repeating the FindControl code on the same control (DRY principle)

Answer (score 1):

You mention there are four controls - Username, Email, Password and ConfirmPassword

The null exception you are seeing is almost certainly because FindControl(X) is returning null

A better way of checking is to do something like:

```
TextBox myTextBox = RegisterUserWizardStep.FindControl(X) as TextBox;

if(myTextBox != null){
  //Continue
}
else{
  //Write out some error information - now you know what the problem is.
}
```

Further, and this isn't related to your immediate error, but then you feed the contents of each of the text boxes directly into your ExecuteInsert method - you'd be better off doing some validation, too, just to check you have expected values.

Answer (score 0):

Code like `RegisterUserWizardStep.FindControl("UserName") as TextBox` will return `null` either if there is no control named `UserName` or if the control named `UserName` can't be cast to a `TextBox`. This is most likely the source of your exception because you attempt to get the property `Text` of a reference that might be `null`.

To better understand where the problem is you can define an extension function:

```
static class ControlExtensions {

  public T Find(this Control parent, String name) where T : Control {
    var control = parent.FindControl(name);
    if (control == null)
      throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Cannot find control named '{0}'.", name);
    var t = control as T;
    if (t == null)
      throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Control named '{0}' does not have type '{1}.", name, typeof(T).Name);
    return t;
  }

}
```

You can then get the `Text` property of the `UserName` control:

```
RegisterUserWizardStep.Find<TextBox>("UserName").Text
```

This call will throw a more descriptive exception if the control isn't found.

Answer (score 0):

In your description you've said that you have a `Username` TextBox.

The code is looking for `RegisterUserWizardStep.FindControl("UserName")`.

Is this a typo in the question? otherwise it could be the cause of the exception.