# error Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.cp_adminsmaster_master' to type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl'

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

i created html generic controls as (ul) and (il)
at runtime 
then iwanna to loop inside my page to get all ul and il crated in run time 
wrote this code to loop inside page controls

```
foreach (HtmlGenericControl item in Page.Controls)
{


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`OfType<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) extension method to get only HtmlGenericControls.

```
foreach (HtmlGenericControl item in Page.Controls.OfType<HtmlGenericControl>())
{


}
```

Comment: You may also need to [search recursively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955769/better-way-to-find-control-in-asp-net).

Comment: sorry but when i created ul and li at runtime and click button these il or ul disappear so page .controls there is no htmlgenericcontrol in it how i keep these htmlgenericcontrols in page when postback

Comment: You'll need to show us how you are adding controls. It's likely that you are only adding them if `IsPostBack` is false. I believe you need to add them to the page in `OnInit` regardless of `IsPostBack`.