# How I use the ItemCommand Event for my ListView in my ASP.NET Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, active-directory, itemcommand

I have a ASP.NET Application with a ListView. In every Row in my ListView I have a LinkButton that open a new webform "Benutzer.aspx". my Problem is that I don't get the Index of this Row. I use the ItemCommand Event but it not work :(

Here my Code:

ASPX:

```
...

        <ItemTemplate>

            <tr runat="server"> 

                <td align="left" ><asp:Label ID="Label1" Text='<%# Eval("Benutzer") %>' runat="server" /></td>
                <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="Label2" Text='<%# Eval("eMail") %>' runat="server" /></td>
                <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="Label3" Text='<%# Eval("Vorname") %>' runat="server" /></td>
                <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="Label4" Text='<%# Eval("Nachname") %>' runat="server" /></td>
                <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="Label5" Text='<%# Eval("Telefon") %>' runat="server" /></td>

             <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Anzeigen" CommandName="Anzeigen" OnCommand="ListView1_ItemCommand" CommandArgument="myArguments"></asp:LinkButton></td>

            </tr>

        </ItemTemplate>

...
```

cs file:

```
...

protected void ListView1_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Anzeigen")
            {
                Label lbText = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label2");

               string email = lbText.Text;

               Session["email"] = email;

               Response.Redirect("Benutzer.aspx");

            }
        }

...
```

What is the matter :(

tarasov

Comment: What's the exact problem? My guess is that you cannot find the label is that right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

First you need to have the index of the button. So in the html code add this in the CommandArgument of the button to get the index:

```
CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'
```

Then in the codebehind:

```
if (e.CommandName == "Anzeigen")
{
      Label lbText = ListView1.Item[e.CommandArgument].FindControl("Label2");
      string email = lbText.Text;           

           Session["email"] = email;           

           Response.Redirect("Benutzer.aspx");           
}
```

Hope I Helped

Comment: Get I a Int DataTyp by Container.DataItemIndex? I get a error by Label lbText = ListView1.Item[(int)e.CommandArgument].FindControl("Label2"); Errortext: The specified cast is not valid. ...but I like your Idea...hope it is a little error ;(

Answer (score 1):

You cannot find the control because it is contained in the child control collection of another server control:

```
<tr runat="server">
```

You need to try to find the control recursively:

Take a look

[Better way to find control in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4955769/1268570)

Or you can use this extension method:

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static Control FindControlRecursively(this Control control, string targetControlID)
    {
        if (control == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var ctrl = control.FindControl(targetControlID);

        if (ctrl == null)
        {
            foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
            {
                ctrl = FindControlRecursively(child, targetControlID);

                if (ctrl != null)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return ctrl;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var ctrl = e.Item.FindControlRecursively("your control ID");
```

Comment: what I need for a Namespace for this class?

Comment: Now I habe remove runat="server" by <tr> tags...and my <Button> shows so: <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Anzeigen" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument="MyArgument" runat="server" />  but I don't can start the Method :protected void Button1_Command(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Select")
            {
                var index = e.Item.FindControlRecursively("Label2"); 

                Label lb = (Label)myListView.Items[selectedIndex].FindControl("Label2");

... } }

Answer (score 1):

The code you have furnished is simply fine... "just remove the 'CommandArgument'  from your listview property , bcoz..its already have the dataindex you are looking for. By specifying a command argument you are overriding the default one.
So just remove the command argument and your code will work fine... :)

Answer (score 1):

I am a VB programmer Check this method may b it gives you some idea

after binding the list with datasource, In the itemCommand do this

```
Dim <sometext> As Label = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("Anzeigen"), Label)

    If e.CommandName = "Anzeigen" Then
     'do what ever you like 
     'also you can use <sometext> if you want to extract data from list
     'simply use <sometext>.<whatproperty>, you can also store it in sessions like the email you are using.

         Session("email") = email         

       Response.Redirect("Benutzer.aspx");  
    End If
```

let me know if it helps you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is the HTML, then build the `OnItemCommand`.

```html
<asp:ListView ID="lvFiles" runat="server"  DataKeyNames="FileName" OnItemCommand="lvFiles_ItemCommand">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr runat="server">
      <td style="width:80px">
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" 
                        ID="SelectEmployeeButton" 
                        Text="Download File"   
                        CommandName='<%#Eval("FileName")%>'
                        CommandArgument='<%#Eval("FileName")%>' />
      </td> 
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Here is the code behind...

```cs
protected void lvFiles_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string v = e.CommandArgument.ToString(); 
}
```