# Is it possible get all images of ascx page in c# code in dnn modules?

Tags: dotnetnuke

Hi i am working on dnn module development , i want to read all images in ascx page to get back to my module and display all images in the module . Is it possible to do it dotnetnuke .

Comment: I think you will have to clarify a bit more about what you are trying to do. IF you are trying to load images into an ASCX file that is fairly easy, though depending on where they are located how you would do it will differ

Comment: @chris hammod I want all the image url in view page load . because i am trying to develop pinterest module . I want all the image url in view page and add that url to a table . In edit page i am going to add pintrest to different images . Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of dotnetnuke, it is rather an asp.net question. Here is the answer from stackoverflow's previous question that is also answer to your question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4955836/261560