# Juice UI - Textbox inside accordion issue

Tags: asp.net, accordion, juice-ui

I'm unable to retrieve the content of a textbox that's inside an accordion panel.  My markup is as follows:

```
<juice:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server">

<juice:AccordionPanel ID="AccordionPanel1" runat="server" Title="Media ID">
<PanelContent>
  <asp:Label ID="LabelMediaID" runat="server" Text="Media ID"     AssociatedControlID="TextBoxMediaID"></asp:Label>    
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxMediaID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</PanelContent>
</juice:AccordionPanel>
```

My server side code is triggered when the user clicks a button:

```
protected void ButtonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Retrieve controls within accordion panels
    TextBox TextBoxMediaID = (TextBox)AccordionPanel1.FindControl("TextBoxMediaID");
    string mediaID= "abc";
    if (TextBoxMediaID != null)
        mediaID= TextBoxMediaID.Text;
```

I'm able to successfully retrieve my textbox control but when I try to access its Text property it's always empty.

Can someone help me?  I'm afraid I'm reasonably new to the world of ASP.NET, Juice etc.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1 - Quick fix

For your page, make `ClientIDMode="static"` in page directive and then use `Request.Form["TextBoxMediaID"]` to get value of your text box.

Option 2 - Debug

Go to debug mode and try `AccordionPanel1.Controls[0].("TextBoxMediaID");` or  `AccordionPanel1.Controls[0].Controls[0].("TextBoxMediaID");` because you don't know how many server side controls are there. Simple solution would be to use [find control recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955769/better-way-to-find-control-in-asp-net).

Comment: Thanks for you help.  I've tried both methods but can't get either to work. Option 1 returns a null string, and my Option 2 'Find control' attempt, using the recursive function passing AccordionPanel1 as a parameter, returns a single textbox whose text is empty.  Do you have any idea why this might be?

Comment: Once you get texbox, you can try `Request.Form[texboxObject.UniqueId]` to get data, this will surely work!

Comment: You'd have thought so - but it doesn't!  It returns null.  I'm beginning to wonder if this is a bug in Juice.

Comment: I would check form tag is not used twice and also check view state settings

Comment: Thanks again.  There is only a single form tag and the view state is enabled.  Any other ideas?  I installed Juice UI using the nuGet package manager in Visual Studio.

Comment: I can review entire aspx page if you can post

Comment: Thanks for all your help and time.  I created a completely new minimal project and I'm pleased to report that I no longer get the issue.  I've no idea what caused it, but it appears that my original project was broken in some way.    Request.Form[texboxObject.UniqueId] now works for me.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that my problem was caused by having an ASP.NET project that used master pages.

If you're not using master pages then

```
TextBox TextBox1 = (TextBox)AccordionPanel1.FindControl("TextBox1");
string content= Request.Form[TextBox1.UniqueId];
```

works perfectly.  However, when using a master page with a ContentPlaceHolder then use the following code:

```
ContentPlaceHolder cph = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("MainContent");
TextBox TextBox1 = (TextBox)AccordionPanel1.FindControl("TextBox1");
string content= Request.Form[cph.UniqueID + "$" + TextBox1.UniqueId];
```

Hopefully this will save someone a lot of time!