# how to access a user define controls iner controls in parent form

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I'm new to windows forms programming so my question may sound little strange.

I have created a user define control (countdown timer) now I'm creating **n** no of it dynamically in a form by Click of a button (Add new timer) its working well and good.
Here is the Creation Code

```
 private void Addnew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       UserControl1.userControl11 = new UserControl1();      
       flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(userControl11);
    }
```

My user control has a `Reset` button  that reset all the content inside the user define control.
it is also working, but What I want Allow user to reset all the Created timers using the “Reset All” button on the form.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do that. Not sure where you are, stuck Does this poorly titled question help you along. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955769/better-way-to-find-control-in-asp-net.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson sorry but i did not understand whats there in the link u given  can u please help a bit more

Comment: @TonyHopkinson as you said there is a lot of way can you tell me an easy way.please help its urgent plz

Comment: @TonyHopkinson one more question if you do not mind.i am using a flowLayoutPanel to show all my user define controls but when i remove /hide one user define control the Blank space remain as it is. the controls following that did not come up Can u help??

Comment: Have you got the right layout direction etc. Have a play about at design time, make sure it's configured correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay one way to do this.

Create a `List<UserControl1>` private member on your form called say _myUserControls

In your `Addnew` Handler  add it to the list.
If you have a remove button, don't forget to remove from `_myUserControls` as well.

Add a Reset method to your `UserControl1`, that does what it needs to do.

Then in your Reset all button click handler

```
foreach(UserControl1 ctrl in _myUserControls)
{
   ctrl.Reset();
}
```

Jobs a good 'un

The answer I referred you to in comments, would be a way of finding all instances of your UserControl1 class, so you wouldn't need an internal list.

Comment: one more question if you do not mind.i am using a  flowLayoutPanel to show all my user define controls but when i remove /hide one user define control the Blank space remain as it is. the controls following that did not come up Can u help???