# How to locate a control within a child control

Tags: webforms

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvSharingList" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="lvSharingList_ItemDataBound">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="tblList" runat="server" style="width: 100%;">
                <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceHolder" style="border: 1px solid rgb(208, 208, 208);"></tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr runat="server" id="tableRow" class="trShareItem" style="border: 1px solid rgb(208, 208, 208);">
                <td runat="server" id="tableCell">
                    <div style="width: 10%; float: left; padding: 5px 5px; margin: 5px 5px; border: 1px solid rgb(208, 208, 208);">
                        <asp:Label Visible="false" ID="lblGroupId" Text='<%# Eval("GroupId") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:Label Visible="false" ID="lblShareId" Text='<%# Eval("ShareId") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:Image ID="imageForFriend" runat="server" CssClass="fromUsername" AlternateText='<%# Eval("Username") %>' />
                        <br />

                        <a href="#" id="aUsername2" runat="server" title='<%# Eval("Username") %>'></a>
                    </div>
                    <div style="width: 45%; float: left; padding: 5px 5px; margin: 5px 5px; border: 1px solid rgb(208, 208, 208);">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblPost" Text='<%# Eval("Post")%>' runat="server" CssClass="sharedPost"></asp:Label><br />
                        <abbr id="abbrId" class="timeago" title='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PostedDate", "{0:M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}") %>' runat="server"></abbr>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblImgFlag" Text='<%# Eval("imgFlag") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:Image ID="imagePhoto" runat="server" CssClass="sharePhotoFile" />
                        <asp:Literal ID="literal" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("video") %>'></asp:Literal>
                    </div>
                    <div style="width: 38%; float: left; height: 100%;">
                        <div>
                            <fieldset>
                                <legend>Comments</legend>
                                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelToResetComment" runat="server">
                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                        <a href="#" runat="server" id="aUsernameForComment"></a>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtShareComment" runat="server" CssClass="txtShareCommentClass"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnComment" UseSubmitBehavior="false" runat="server" Text="Comment" CssClass="btn btn-small btn-primary" OnClick="btnComment_Click" />
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                        <asp:ListView ID="listViewShareComments" runat="server">
                                            <LayoutTemplate>
                                                <ul id="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server">
                                                </ul>
                                            </LayoutTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblUsernameID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Username") %>' CssClass="txtShareCommentClass"></asp:Label>&nbsp;:&nbsp;
                                                <asp:Label ID="txtShareCommentID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Comment") %>' CssClass="txtShareCommentClass"></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <ItemSeparatorTemplate>
                                                <br />
                                            </ItemSeparatorTemplate>
                                        </asp:ListView>
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                    <Triggers>
                                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnComment" EventName="Click" />
                                    </Triggers>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

I have the above example and I would like to know the best approach to locate a control within a child control. In the above example I have a ListView control that has a tableRow followed by tableCell. I have a listview within the tableCell. Why cant I locate the child listview directly from the page control? Why do I have to locate each runat=server control and then find the child control?

The following way works fine! I would like to know is there a better way to locate the child listview control?

```
HtmlTableCell tCell = (HtmlTableCell)lblShaId.Parent;
                UpdatePanel updatePanel1 = (UpdatePanel)tCell.FindControl("UpdatePanel1");                
                ListView listViewShareComments1 = (ListView)updatePanel1.FindControl("listViewShareComments");
                listViewShareComments1.DataSource = userMethods.GetAdminGroupShareComments(Convert.ToInt32(lblShaId.Text));
                listViewShareComments1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just the way FindControl was implemented in ASP.Net - c.f. [Better way to find control in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955769/better-way-to-find-control-in-asp-net) for a more detailed discussion on some of the likely reasons it was implemented this way as well as some techniques on how to search for a control in a recursive manner.