# Not able to find the web control on code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, click, web-controls, linkbutton

I have some controls on a page and i am not able to access the controls in code behind, it is coming in scientific intelligence. I am getting the cause of that.

here is my HTML code of web control:

```
   <%@ Control Language="c#" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="DNNInfo.Modules.Classifieds.Controls.CompanyClassifiedList" %>
   <div id="divDetailsDownloadFile" runat="server" class="DNNInfo_ClassifiedDownloads" visible="false">
      <asp:LinkButton ID="linkDownloadFile" Text="Download File" runat="server" />
    </div>
```

i am talking about the linkbutton here.

here is code behind code:

```
namespace DNNInfo.Modules.Classifieds.Controls
{
   public class CompanyClassifiedList : PortalModuleBase
    { override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        base.OnInit(e);
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {

        try
        {
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Page_Load);
           LinkButton linkDownload_File = (LinkButton)this.FindControl("linkDownloadFile");

            if (linkDownload_File != null)
            {
                linkDownload_File.Click += new EventHandler(this.linkDownloadFile_Click);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
  }
}
```

It always return null in "linkDownload_File". i am not able to recognize the error. what is the cause for this behavior.

any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** i have checked by made div visible.. but still its returning null

Comment: Maybe because you are redenring your DIV's visible = false?

Comment: @LouisvanTonder i have already checked that, it is not because of that

Comment: From where are you calling this code? Shouldn't you specify your page? Or run it from code behind of the page? Right now, does this.Page equal to the actual page your control resides on?

Comment: I can't remember if the controls are initialized before `InitializeComponent` or not. Can you move the code to `Page_Load` for example?

Comment: but there some also some other controls and they are working fine.. i am treating the same with them too

Answer (score 1):

You need to look for it recursively, because it is within DIV. As an alternate way of doing this is to use Page.FindControl this way:

http://blog.codinghorror.com/recursive-pagefindcontrol/

but perhaps more recommended way:

[Better way to find control in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955769/better-way-to-find-control-in-asp-net)

or try to remove runat="server" on DIV

Answer (score 0):

did you try the below:-

LinkButton linkDownload_File  = (LinkButton)divDetailsDownloadFile.FindControl("linkDownloadFile");