# How to find table cell in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, itemtemplate

I want to hide an itemtemplate's data in listview using the td visibility property. Once I click a button it should show the data again that's within the itemtemplate. However, I cannot find the td control using c# in the code behind. Is there a way to find this control or another way to handle this?

```
 <asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="ButtonClick" />
 <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">

     <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListView ID="SectionListView" runat="server" InsertItemPosition="FirstItem" OnPagePropertiesChanged="SectionListView_PagePropertiesChanged">

             <ItemTemplate>
                 <tr style="">
                        <td></td>
                        <td id="row1" style="visibility:hidden;" runat="server">
                                <asp:Label ID="SectionItemLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SectionItem") %>' />
                        </td>
                 </tr>
             </ItemTemplate>
```

Here is part of the code for the button click:

```
protected void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var temp = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell)Page.Master.FindControl("MainContent").FindControl("row1");
    }
```

Comment: Where is the button you are clicking that triggers `ButtonClick()`? And where/what is "MainControl"?

Comment: @j.f. The Button Click is outside the multiview and the "maincontent" is the content place holder. Updated code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of issues. First, when you try to find "row1" within "MainContent", if won't find it because "row1" is actually a child of other children of "MainContent". It won't find them recursively unless [you tell them to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955769/better-way-to-find-control-in-asp-net).

Second, since each `ListViewItem` within your ListView contains "row1", they are each given their own unique ID, such as `SectionListView_ctrl0_row1`, `SectionListView_ctrl1_row1`, etc. Because of this, you need to use FindControl() on each `ListViewItem`.

But, because you need to do it on each `ListViewItem` and because each `ListViewItem` contains "row1", each row will get the same property (i.e. all visible or all invisible). Here is how that could be done:

```
protected void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem lvi in SectionListView.Items)
    {
        if (lvi.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            HtmlTableCell row1 = (HtmlTableCell)lvi.FindControl("row1");
            row1.Style.Add("visibility", "hidden");
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to style each cell individually, they would each need to be named differently. It is common to attach some sort of number or database ID to the end of the ID if that is the case.

Comment: Do I need to keep this line? <td id="row1" style="visibility:hidden;" runat="server">

Comment: Well you definitely need `id="row1"` and `runat="server"`. Keeping the style is up to you and whether or not you need it to be hidden to start.

Comment: Thanks everything worked! I will just hide everything on page load

Comment: If I use another view in multiview it does not find the id. Any idea?