# Usercontrol findcontrol property thrown Object reference not set to an instance of an object?

Tags: c#

I have two usercontrol UC_1.ascx & Uc_2.ascx.

I tried to bind UC_2 textbox values from my UC_1.

Below is my code :

```
 System.Web.UI.UserControl UserControl1 = (System.Web.UI.UserControl)Page.FindControl("UC_2");
if (UserControl1 != null)
{
    TextBox txt = UserControl1.FindControl("txtTest") as TextBox; //thwon object null reference error.
    txt.Text = "test123123123213";
}
```

But I am getting error from calling `UserControl1` object.

Error like :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: You cannot find control like that, refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4955836/1432033

Comment: `NullReferenceException` is a common situation for beginner programmers. The link provided should help you understand the problem. Then use the debugger to find what/where/when you have a variable that is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to check that your `UserControl1` is not null.

2) If it isn't, check that `UserControl1.FindControl("txtTest") as TextBox` doesn't equal to null.

The code is equivalent to the following expression except that the expression variable is evaluated only one time.
expression is `type ? (type)expression : (type)null`   the problem is in the type you try to cast.

Comment: I am getting UserControl1 is null. How to avoid that. Can you please help me to solve.

Comment: what is the answer you get from `UserControl1.FindControl("txtTest")`?

Comment: I want to pass the values to UC_2.ascx textbox from my UC_1.ascx. But i am getting null while assigning UserControl1.

Comment: @Dhamo, i edited the answer

Answer (score -1):

Replace
`TextBox txt = UserControl1.FindControl("txtTest") as TextBox;`

by

```
if(UserControl1.FindControl("txtTest") != null)
{
TextBox txt = UserControl1.FindControl("txtTest") as TextBox; 
txt.Text = "test123123123213";
}
```

FindControl is not able to locate txtText, Keep in mind that it only searches direct children of the container.

Comment: I am getting error from if conditions Error Like : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: have corrected code to check for null.