# Cannot read value from dynamically created textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to retrieve a textbox value in a button click event, but as soon as the button is clicked, the postback fires and the value is empty. I have tried to create the textbox in a (`!isPostBack`) but that doesn't seem to work.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Form.Controls.Add(t);
}

protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     predictionList = dc.getPredictions(Convert.ToInt32(Session["accountId"]));
     fixtureList = dc.getFixtures();
     t.CssClass = "panel panel-success table table-striped";
     sortLists();
     foreach (Fixture f in newList)
     {
          TableRow tr = new TableRow();
          TableCell tc1= new TableCell();
          TextBox tb1= new TextBox();
          tb1.ID = "tb1";
          tc1.Controls.Add(tb1);
          tr.Cells.Add(tc1);
          t.Rows.Add(tr);
     }
}
```

Here I add the control, and here I want to process whatever is in the textbox:

```
protected void btSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     foreach (TableRow r in t.Rows)
     {
         string textboxRead= ((TextBox)r.FindControl("tb1")).text;
         int textboxInt = Convert.ToInt32(textboxRead);
     }
}
```

Comment: are you getting an error?

Comment: No, there is no error. The value just is empty.

Comment: In the for loop, you are assigning textbox1 as an ID of all the created textboxes. I do not know if this is related to your problem here, but it might cause another problems.

Comment: @Eray I am aware of the fact that i need to dynamically create textboxes. and also that i need to create dynamic id's. thats not related to the problem. i cannot read the value from a single textbox either.

Comment: the object t is not clearly defined in your code, but it is used to reference the text boxes. What sort of type is it? I'm not getting an error using the example shown.

Comment: Be sure to mark this as answered, if somebody has solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that `FindControl()` is not finding the textbox because it doesn't work recursively?

i.e. You have added the TextBox to a `TableCell`, but you are performing your `FindControl()` call on the `TableRow`, not the `TableCell`. So either call FindControl() from the Cell or use a recursive version.

For a recursive version of FindControl(), see: [Better way to find control in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955769/better-way-to-find-control-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TextBox tb1;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        tb1 = ((TextBox)r.FindControl("tb1"));                
    }
}

protected void btSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string textboxRead = tb1.Text; // here you can get the tb1.Text
     int textboxInt = Convert.ToInt32(textboxRead);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

```
protected void AddTextBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = pnlTextBoxes.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList().Count + 1;
    this.CreateTextBox("txtDynamic" + index);
}


private void CreateTextBox(string id)
{
    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
    txt.ID = id;
    pnlTextBoxes.Controls.Add(txt);

    Literal lt = new Literal();
    lt.Text = "<br />";
    pnlTextBoxes.Controls.Add(lt);
}
```

see this link for details:
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Get-Value-Text-of-dynamically-created-TextBox-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the ID's to all of your dynamically created controls. This is mandatory to prevent any ambiguity on post-back.

That includes `tr`, `tc1`, `tb1` and maybe even `t` controls.

Also, to find the value, use this snippet:

```
protected void btSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TableRow tr in t.Rows)
    {
        var tc1 = (TableCell)tr.FindControl("tc1");
        var tb1 = (TextBox)tc1.FindControl("tb1");
        int textboxInt = Convert.ToInt32(tb1.Text);
     }
}
```