# Filling a webpage textbox without an id

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

Here's the html code for the page:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="TextInput"><font color="#7f2b1b">Account</font></label>
    <input name="Username" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Account ID." required="" type="text">
</div>
```

And here's my attempt of doing it in C#:

```
foreach (HtmlElement o in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("class"))
        {
            HtmlElement yourElement;
            if (o.GetAttribute("name") == "Username")
            {
                yourElement = o;
                yourElement.SetAttribute("value", "FillingText");
                break;
            }

        }
```

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: @Noobzilla We'd need more info to help you. First off, is this web forms, MVC or what? Second, why can't you just use an ID on the textbox? Third, why are you manipulating the DOM in C#, why not use the technologies Microsoft has supplied, which of course depends on the answer to the first question.

Comment: webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("class") -> webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("INPUT")

Comment: There is a good answer here: [Better way to find control in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4955836/3472827)