# Loop on all textboxes in page

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, foreach, textbox

In my project I have 5 textboxes.
I want to find the text of each one on foreach loop.
Thant's works for me, but when I set a design on page, it doesn't work.

My code:

```
foreach (Control c in Page.Controls)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in c.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl is TextBox)
        {
            string text = ((TextBox)ctrl).Text;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
            {
                Zone.addPermission(new User(text));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: define "doesn't work"

Comment: I suggest using the `ControlFinder` class proposed by Jimmy in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955769/better-way-to-find-control-in-asp-net.

Comment: Probably the controls are more deeply nested than the OP's assuming, since he only goes down one level, not arbitrarily deep.

Comment: so much unnecessary work, why don't you place the textboxes in a panel and loop through them or reference your textboxes directly?