# How to change image controls images with loop

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 5 image control in a page with Id's image1 trough image5 and I want to change those controls images in codebehind with a loop.in fact I catch some images name in a folder and after that I want assign imageUrl with this names.
How can I do that ?
There is a way in a loop I can access specific image control with postfix i where i is a loop counter? Or other way?

Comment: About half-way down this question is an answer showing how to find a control by Id (the one with 36 upvotes) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955769/better-way-to-find-control-in-asp-net also see this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y81z8326(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For i as Integer = 1 to 5
    Dim img As Image = CType(Form.FindControl("image" & i.ToString()), Image)
    img.ImageUrl = getImageUrlForI(i)
Next
```

This works for images, but generally speaking you could loop through every control in the page, then check their type, and 'do your thing' depending on its type

Answer (score 0):

You can add the 5 image controls in a List and use a foreach-loop to iterate through it