# Can't Find Control Within Gridview Edit Item Template

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the below code with which I'm trying to find the `dropDownList` ID of `SupplierSelectDropDown` in the `sqldatasource` update command, but nothing I'm trying is working.

I have tried to use `ctl00$Content$DetailsPageControl$PurchaseTabGridView$DXEFL$edit0_4$SupplierSelectDropDown` but that id changes depending on the number of rows. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<dx:TabPage Name="Purchase" Text="Purchase">
  <ContentCollection>
    <dx:ContentControl runat="server">
      <dx:ASPxGridView ID="PurchaseTabGridView" runat="server" Theme="Youthful" KeyFieldName="detail_id" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="PurchaseTabDetail">
        <SettingsPager Visible="False"></SettingsPager>
        <SettingsDataSecurity AllowDelete="False" AllowInsert="False" />
        <Columns>
          <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowEditButton="True" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="0" Caption=" ">
          </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
          <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Code" FieldName="code" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="6">
            <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
          </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
          <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Description" FieldName="description" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="7">
            <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
          </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
          <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="supply_trader_id" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" Visible="False" VisibleIndex="10">
          </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
          <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="supplyname" Caption="Supplier" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" Visible="true" VisibleIndex="8">
            <EditItemTemplate>
              <asp:DropDownList ID="SupplierSelectDropDown" DataSourceID="SupplierSelect" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("supply_trader_id") %>' DataValueField="trader_id" DataTextField="combined" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
          </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        </Columns>
      </dx:ASPxGridView>
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: You should post your C# code even it doesn't seem to work so far. We prefer to help you with idea that why your code may not work as you expect but write the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set **ClientIDMode** to *static* in your dropdown properties to avoid generated id's.
Then perform a [recursive search to find the control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955769/better-way-to-find-control-in-asp-net) in order to save you the task of figuring out which is the parent container.