# How to move through all controls inside controls in Asp.Net WebForm?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, controls, extension-methods

How to move through all controls inside Panel Web Control or any other control?

control.FindControls("name") finds only controls in the same level only

below is an answer with high speed and lower resources with multitasking

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Better way to find control in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955769/better-way-to-find-control-in-asp-net)

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/recursive-pagefindcontrol/ may be of interest.

Comment: below is a high speed solution with lower memory and multitasking

Answer (score 0):

```
/// <summary>
/// Start from Control and move through all inside controls to check if can execute and 
/// execute ctrlAction if canExecute results true
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">
/// Any Control or object inherits System.Web.UI.Control
/// </typeparam>
/// <param name="ctrl">
/// the System.Web.UI.Control to traverse from and inside
/// </param>
/// <param name="ctrlAction">
/// the action to execute on the valid control
/// </param>
/// <param name="canExecute">
/// to check if the current reached control is valid for ctrlAction execution
/// </param>
public static void ExApply<T>(
    this Control ctrl, Action<T> ctrlAction, Predicate<T> canExecute = null) where T : Control
{
    // if ctrl is null return null
    if (ctrl == null) { return; }
    // to handle multitasking on the valid controls
    LinkedList<Task> taskList = new LinkedList<Task>();
    // start control traverse through all controls from and inside
    ctrl._exApply(canExecute, ctrlAction, taskList);
    // Waiting not finished, clean and clear resources
    taskList._exWaitAndDispose();
}

/// <summary>
/// Start from ControlCollection and move through all inside controls to check if can execute and 
/// execute ctrlAction if canExecute results true
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">
/// Any Control or object inherits System.Web.UI.Control
/// </typeparam>
/// <param name="ctrls">
/// the System.Web.UI.ControlCollection to traverse from and inside
/// </param>
/// <param name="ctrlAction">
/// the action to execute on the valid control
/// </param>
/// <param name="canExecute">
/// to check if the current reached control is valid for ctrlAction execution
/// </param>
public static void ExApply<T>(
    this ControlCollection ctrls, Action<T> ctrlAction, Predicate<T> canExecute = null)
    where T : Control
{
    // if ctrls is null return null
    if (ctrls == null) { return; }
    // to handle multitasking on the valid controls
    LinkedList<Task> taskList = new LinkedList<Task>();
    // start control traverse through all controls from and inside
    ctrls._exApply(canExecute, ctrlAction, taskList);
    // Waiting not finished, clean and clear resources
    taskList._exWaitAndDispose();
}

 private static void _exApply<T>(
    this Control ctrl, Predicate<T> canExecute, Action<T> ctrlAction, LinkedList<Task> taskList)
    where T : Control
{
    // if ctrl is null no more moves needed
    if (ctrl == null) { return; }

    // if ctrl can be casted and has no empty id
    if ((ctrl is T castedCtrl) && castedCtrl.ID.ExIsNotNone())
    {
        // if canExecute is null or returned true result
        if (canExecute == null || (canExecute != null && canExecute(castedCtrl)))
        {
            // add castedCtrl as an asynchronous task
            taskList.AddLast(Task.Run(() => ctrlAction(castedCtrl)));
            // check first node task if completed to remove and dispose
            taskList._exDisposeFirsts();
        }
    }

    // move more deep into inside controls 
    if (ctrl.Controls != null && ctrl.Controls.Count > 0)
    {
        ctrl.Controls._exApply(canExecute, ctrlAction, taskList);
    }
}

private static void _exApply<T>(
    this ControlCollection ctrls, Predicate<T> canExecute, Action<T> ctrlAction,
    LinkedList<Task> taskList) where T : Control
{
    for (int index = 0; index < ctrls.Count; index++)
    {
        // move through control to validate and apply ctrlAction
        ctrls[index]?._exApply(canExecute, ctrlAction, taskList);
    }
}

private static void _exDisposeFirsts(this LinkedList<Task> taskList)
{
    while (taskList.Count > 0 && taskList.First.Value.IsCompleted)
    {
        taskList.First.Value.Dispose();
        taskList.RemoveFirst();
    }
}

private static void _exWaitAndDispose(this LinkedList<Task> taskList)
{
    taskList._exDisposeFirsts();
    if (taskList.Count < 1) { return; }
    Task[] tasks = new Task[taskList.Count];
    taskList.CopyTo(tasks, 0);
    taskList.Clear();
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    tasks.ExDispose();
}

/// <summary>
/// Smaller Size name and usage from "string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text)" Indicates whether a 
/// specified string is null, empty, or consists only of white-space characters.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="text">The string to test</param>
/// <returns>
/// true if the value parameter is null or System.String.Empty, or if value consists 
/// exclusively of white-space characters.
/// </returns>
public static bool ExIsNone(this string text) => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text);

/// <summary>
/// Smaller Size name and usage from "!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text)" Indicates whether a 
/// specified string is not null, not empty, or not consists only of white-space characters.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="text">The string to test</param>
/// <returns>
/// true if the value parameter is not null or not System.String.Empty, or if value not consists 
/// exclusively of white-space characters.
/// </returns>
public static bool ExIsNotNone(this string text) => text.ExIsNone().ExIs(false);

/// <summary>
/// Use for easier code reading instead of inverse ! character and ambiguous names
/// </summary>
/// <param name="value">value to test</param>
/// <param name="compareValue">value to compare with</param>
/// <returns>true is equal otherwise false</returns>
public static bool ExIs(this bool value, bool compareValue) => value == compareValue;
```