# having textbox id's in array need to set value dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

what i did so for

```
var allLiveIDS = Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(key => key.Contains("txt")).ToList();
for (int i = 2; i < allLiveIDS.Count; i++)
        {
          var Textt= this.FindControl(allLiveIDS[i]) as TextBox;
            Textt.Text = "Some Value";
}
```

but getting null in Textt, pLease share how can i set value to text box

Comment: Is this WebForms?

Comment: Based on the assumption that this is webforms, I'd recommend to check out this SO post. The answer to that post will guide you to a solution how to find your controls in the control tree:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955769/better-way-to-find-control-in-asp-net