# FindControl() returns null when searching for dynamic control

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

In my requirement I am creating dynamic controls by two events

1. Dropdownlist `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event
2. Onclick button event

In OnSelectedIndexChanged event i have created number of dynamic textbox.

Here I have create two dynamic textboxes. 
[image]

I am getting all enquiry product list based on enquiry number from the dynamic textboxes on button click event

[image]

All are dynamic controls

While saving the productlist the checkbox control return null value

```
  protected void ddlenqChaged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getenqTextbox();
    }
    protected void btnSearchClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tblbill.Visible = true;

        if (Convert.ToString(ViewState["Generated"]) != "true")
        {
            CreateDynamicControls();
            ViewState["Generated"] = "true";
        }
    }


protected void getenqTextbox()
    {
        enqPanel.Controls.Clear();
        if (Convert.ToInt32(ddlNoofEnq.SelectedValue) > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= Convert.ToInt32(ddlNoofEnq.SelectedValue); i++)
            {
                TextBox _txtCode = new TextBox();
                _txtCode.ID = "txtEnqqNo" + i;
                _txtCode.Attributes.Add("ClientIDMode", "Static");
                _txtCode.Width = 75;
                _txtCode.CssClass = "AtCompleteByEnq";
                enqPanel.Controls.Add(_txtCode);
            }
        }
    }


protected void CreateDynamicControls()
    {

        int m = 1;
        //int encount = click.buttonclick;

        if (Convert.ToInt32(ddlNoofEnq.SelectedValue) > 0)
        {
            Table tbldynamic = new Table();

            for (int k = 1; k <= Convert.ToInt32(ddlNoofEnq.SelectedValue); k++)
            {
                Panel1.Controls.Clear();
                TextBox tb = (TextBox)enqPanel.FindControl("txtEnqqNo" + k);
                if (tb != null)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text))
                    {
                        List<Enquiry_ProductListBLL> objlst = Enquiry_ProductListBLL.GetEnquiry_ProductListBLLs(tb.Text);

                        foreach (Enquiry_ProductListBLL item in objlst)
                        {
                            TableRow tr = new TableRow();

                            TableCell tc = new TableCell();
                            TableCell tc1 = new TableCell();
                            TableCell tc2 = new TableCell();
                            TableCell tc3 = new TableCell();
                            TableCell tc4 = new TableCell();
                            TableCell tc5 = new TableCell();

                            TableCell tc6 = new TableCell();

                            Master_ProductBLL objpdt = Master_ProductBLL.GetMaster_ProductBLL(item.ProductId);

                            CheckBox _chkRowNo = new CheckBox();
                            _chkRowNo.ID = "chkRowNo" + m;
                            _chkRowNo.Text = m.ToString();
                            _chkRowNo.Attributes.Add("ClientIDMode", "Static");
                            _chkRowNo.Attributes.Add("onclick", "getEnable(this);");
                            _chkRowNo.Checked = true;

                            TextBox _txtCode = new TextBox();
                            _txtCode.ID = "txtCodeRow" + m;
                            _txtCode.Attributes.Add("ClientIDMode", "Static");
                            _txtCode.Enabled = false;
                            _txtCode.Width = 75;
                            _txtCode.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off");
                            _txtCode.Text = objpdt.Code;

                            HiddenField _hdnPdtId = new HiddenField();
                            _hdnPdtId.ID = "hdnPdtId" + m;
                            _hdnPdtId.Value = item.ProductId.ToString();

                            HiddenField _hdEnqNo = new HiddenField();
                            _hdEnqNo.ID = "hdEnqNo" + m;
                            _hdEnqNo.Value = item.EnqNo;

                            _hdnPdtId.Value = item.ProductId.ToString();
                            TextBox _txtPdtName = new TextBox();
                            _txtPdtName.ID = "txtPdtNameRow" + m;
                            _txtPdtName.Attributes.Add("ClientIDMode", "Static");
                            _txtPdtName.Enabled = false;
                            _txtPdtName.Width = 150;
                            _txtPdtName.CssClass = "AtCompleteByName";
                            _txtPdtName.Text = objpdt.Name;


                            TextBox _txtQty = new TextBox();
                            _txtQty.ID = "txtQtyRow" + m;
                            _txtQty.Width = 80;
                            _txtQty.MaxLength = 8;
                            _txtQty.Attributes.Add("ClientIDMode", "Static");
                            //_txtQty.Attributes.Add("onblur", "GetTotal(this)");
                            //_txtQty.Enabled = false;
                            _txtQty.Text = item.Count.ToString();

                            DropDownList ddlUnits = new DropDownList();
                            ddlUnits.ID = "ddlUnits" + m;
                            ddlUnits.CssClass = "dropdowncss";
                            ddlUnits.Width = 100;
                            Bindings.BindUnitName(ddlUnits);
                            ddlUnits.Items.FindByText(item.PP).Selected = true;

                            tc.Controls.Add(_chkRowNo);
                            tc1.Controls.Add(_txtCode);
                            tc2.Controls.Add(_txtPdtName);
                            tc2.Controls.Add(_hdnPdtId);
                            tc2.Controls.Add(_hdEnqNo);
                            tc3.Controls.Add(_txtBrand);
                            tc4.Controls.Add(_txtThickness);
                            tc5.Controls.Add(ddlUnits);
                            tc6.Controls.Add(_txtQty);

                            tc.Attributes.Add("Width", "50px");
                            tr.Attributes.Add("id", "Rowid" + m);
                            tr.Attributes.Add("class", "paidRw");

                            tr.Cells.Add(tc);
                            tr.Cells.Add(tc1);
                            tr.Cells.Add(tc2);
                            tr.Cells.Add(tc3);
                            tr.Cells.Add(tc4);
                            tr.Cells.Add(tc5);
                            tr.Cells.Add(tc6);


                            tbldynamic.Rows.Add(tr);
                            m++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Panel1.Controls.Add(tbldynamic);
        }
    }
```

Here I have override OnLoad event

```
 protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        CreateDynamicControls();
        getenqTextbox();

    }
```

My problem is i cannot find controls from Panel1

```
CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)Panel1.FindControl(chkId);
                    if (chk != null)
                    {
                        if (chk.Checked == true)
                        {
                            //my process
                        }
                    }
```

FindControl returns null value.

Here I have create dynamic controls two times.

I cannot have any problem with enquiry textbox, it was created first, but the second time button click event controls are return null.

Comment: If i remove getenqTextbox() method It will works perfect. I have added directly Enquiry textbox in .aspx. Only one event dynamic controls is working. How to rectify it.

Comment: This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955769/better-way-to-find-control-in-asp-net) demonstrates several recursive and non-recursive solutions.

Answer (score 0):

FindControl does not walk the hierarchy. 
See doc [Control.FindControl()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx)

*This method will find a control only if the control is directly contained by the specified container; that is, the method does not search throughout a hierarchy of controls within controls.*

Since your CheckBox is not a first-level child of the Panel, it cannot be retrieved this way. If you need a generic solution, I suggest to implement a recursive FindControl.