# How to find user control of an ASP.NET page inside of event of another user control on that ASP.NET page EDIT: different content placeholders? 

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, findcontrol, contentplaceholder

I have a ASP.NET page with 2 user controls registered. The first one has only one button in it. The second one is simple text and hidden on default. What I want is to make the second one visible when the button in the first one is clicked (that is on button click event).

ASP.NET page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="test" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/UC_button.ascx" TagName="button" TagPrefix="UC" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/UC_text.ascx" TagName="text" TagPrefix="UC" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MyTestContent" Runat="Server">
    <UC:button ID="showbutton1" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MyTestContent2" Runat="Server">
    <UC:text runat="server" Visible="false" ID="text1" />
</asp:Content>
```

UC_Button.ascx.cs:

```
protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btnSender = (Button)sender;
    Page parentPage = btnSender.Page;
    UserControl UC_text = (UserControl)parentPage.FindControl("text1");
    UC_text.Visible = true;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  I get well known `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error on that last line of the code.

**EDIT:**

One thing I forgot to mention when first posting this. User controls are in different `<asp:Content></asp:Content>` controls (I edited upper example). If I put them in the same placeholder code works just fine. If I put them in the separate content placeholders I can't find them in any way with findcontrol. Why is that and how can I find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found solution until better one comes my way. The problem is, as Jamie Dixon pointed out (thank you Jamie):

*`The FindControl method does not do a deep search for controls. It looks directly in the location you specify for the control you're requesting.`*

So because I have user controls in different contentplaceholders I must first find targeted placeholder (where the user control reside) and then I can search for user control inside it:

```
protected void Dodaj_Feed_Panel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ContentPlaceHolder MySecondContent = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Parent.Parent.FindControl("MyTestContent2");

        UserControl UC_text = (UserControl)MySecondContent.FindControl("text1");
        UC_text.Visible = true;
    }
```

what really annoys and confuses me is the `this.Parent.Parent` part because I know it's not the best solution (in case I change the hierarchy a bit this code will break). What this part of code actually does is that it goes two levels up in page hierarchy (that is page where both user controls are). I don't know what the difference with `this.Page` is because for me it means the same but is not working for me.

Long term solution would be something like server side "jQuery-like selectors" (it can found elements no matter where they are in hierarchy). Anyone has a better solution?

Comment: the better solution:  MVC :)

Answer (score 6):

please check below:

```
UserControl UC_text = (UserControl)this.NamingContainer.FindControl("text1");
```

Answer (score 2):

The FindControl method does not do a deep search for controls. It looks directly in the location you specify for the control you're requesting.

In your case, what you'll need to do is something like:

```
UserControl UC_text = (UserControl)Content1.FindControl("text1");
```

You can also see my question here: [IEnumerable and Recursion using yield return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055927/ienumerable-and-recursion-using-yield-return) that demonstrates a method of finding deep controls by type.

Comment: `Content1` of page isn't visible/accessible from inner user control of that page (or am I completely wrong?)

Comment: I think you're right. Looking at your code you should simply be able to reference text1 directly, without having to use FindControl.

Comment: I have user controls in different content placeholders so I cannot reference it directly (gives same error). See above I updated my question/problem.

Answer (score 0):

use the id of user control，then put the controls (e.g Textbox) inside panel then
try this code from the main page

example:

```
TextBox txt = (TextBox)showbutton1.FindControl("Textbox1");
```

for updating with udpatepanel:
 TextBox txt = (TextBox)showbutton1.FindControl("Textbox1");
  txt.Text="Hello World!";

```
((UpdatePanel)showbutton1.FindControl("UpdatePanel1")).Update();
```