# Controls not initializing in UserControls Asp.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-user-controls

I am new to asp.net and I have user control and i am creating its instance. But for some reason all controls are null.

```
public static void LoadRulesLogic()
    {
        WebUserControls control = new WebUserControls();
        control.LoadRules(); //Controls null here
    }
```

How do i initialize all controls before calling LoadRules method?

Comment: What is `WebUserControls`? There is no standard .NET class having this name - so I suppose it is your custom class. Thus, it's hard to say what can be wrong without seeing its source.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev WebUserControl  is my custom class which inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl class

Comment: @Richa can you show us the WebUserControls Class?

Comment: Refer to this
[How to find user control of an ASP.NET page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828124/how-to-find-user-control-of-an-asp-net-page-inside-of-event-of-another-user-cont) You will need to find or load the UC in your page then use it.