# Replace recursion with TimerCallback for iterations over all variations

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to find an algorithm to print with intervals all variation of values in array. It looks simple to understand it, but I can't find how to manage the data for this...

For example I have the list of following objects (the number of arguments in list can vary):

```
List<Arg> lst = new List<Arg>();
lst.Add(new Arg { Name = "a", InitValue = 1, MaxValue = 2, Step = 1 });
lst.Add(new Arg { Name = "b", InitValue = 2, MaxValue = 6, Step = 2 });
lst.Add(new Arg { Name = "c", InitValue = 4, MaxValue = 12, Step = 4 });
```

Now I need to iterate over all args variations (each iteration has all arguments) and print them. The challenge is how to do it with intervals between the iterations and not to use Thread.Sleep. I want to use System.Threading.Timer and print each variation in TimerCallback method.

Example output:

```
a = 1, b = 2, c = 4
a = 1, b = 2, c = 8
a = 1, b = 2, c = 12

a = 1, b = 4, c = 4
a = 1, b = 4, c = 8
a = 1, b = 4, c = 12

a = 1, b = 6, c = 4
a = 1, b = 6, c = 8
a = 1, b = 6, c = 12

a = 2, b = 2, c = 4
a = 2, b = 2, c = 8
a = 2, b = 2, c = 12

a = 2, b = 4, c = 4
a = 2, b = 4, c = 8
a = 2, b = 4, c = 12

a = 2, b = 6, c = 4
a = 2, b = 6, c = 8
a = 2, b = 6, c = 12
```

I can do it easily with recursion, but it will not work with TimerCallback...

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want intervals between the iterations if you are just printing?

Comment: It will be used to change process configuration and each configuration should run for X minutes. After X minutes i need to change configuration to next variant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can easily do it with recursion and [`yield`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx).

With `yield`, you can write your code very similar to the way you normally would, and have your function return an `IEnumerator` instead, using `yield return` to return the next item from the enumerator. Then, at each timer event, simply get the next element.

Here's a little example I constructed of how you would use `yield` in a similar way:

```
public class Test
{
    static System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator;
    static void Main()
    {
        // Display powers of 2 up to the exponent of 8: 
        enumerator = Power(2, 8);
        bool done = false;
        while (!done)
            done = !timerEvent();
    }

    static bool timerEvent()
    {
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            return false;
        else
            Console.Write("{0} ", enumerator.Current);
        return true;
    }

    // This will be your function
    static System.Collections.IEnumerator Power(int number, int exponent)
    {
        int result = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < exponent; i++)
        {
            result = result * number;
            yield return result;
        }
    }
    // Output: 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256
}
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/XR9z7I).

Since you mentioned that you can easily do it with recursion, I'll leave applying this to your problem up to you.

To use `yield` with recursion, you may have to [change your code a little](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055927/ienumerable-and-recursion-using-yield-return).