# In C#, how can I force iteration over IEnumerable within nested foreach loops?

Tags: c#

I have two `IEnumerable`s:

```
IEnumerable<string> first = ...
IEnumerable<string> second = ...
```

I want to create a second `IEnumerable<string>` that is the concatenation of each element of each `IEnumerable`.

For example:

```
IEnumerable<string> first = new [] {"a", "b"};
IEnumerable<string> second = new [] {"c", "d"};

foreach (string one in first)
{
   foreach (string two in second)
   {
      yield return string.Format("{0} {1}", one, two);
   }
}
```

This would produce:

`"a c"; "a d"; "b c"; "b d";`

The problem is, sometimes one of the two `IEnumerable`s is empty:

```
IEnumerable<string> first = new string[0];
IEnumerable<string> second = new [] {"c", "d"};
```

In this case, the nested `foreach` construct never reaches the `yield return` statement. When either `IEnumerable` is empty, I would like the result to just be the list of the non-empty `IEnumerable`.

How can I produce the combinations I am looking for?

**EDIT**: 
In reality, I have three different `IEnumerable`s I am trying to combine, so adding if conditions for every possible permutation of empty `IEnumerable` seems bad. If that's the only way, then I guess I'll have to do it that way.

Comment: Look into the Zip linq operator.  It takes two enumerables and allows you to traverse through both.  If sizes aren't the same put logic in to account for that.

Comment: @JohnPeters He's not zipping the sequences.

Comment: "When either IEnumerable is empty, I would like the result to just be the list of the non-empty IEnumerable" Then you should handle that case before your loops.

Comment: Use indexes, if zip doesn't work for you.

Comment: Just for clarity can you please include example outputs in the question for `first` being empty and for `second` being empty.

Comment: You can assume list contains one null element in case it is null or empty (so, first ?? new string[] {null}) and act accordingly in yield (not include null strings in result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `Enumerable.DefaultIfEmpty()` to enumerate collection even if there is no items.

```
IEnumerable<string> first = new string[0]; 
IEnumerable<string> second = new[] { "a", "b" };
IEnumerable<string> third = new[] { "c", null, "d" };

var permutations = 
     from one in first.DefaultIfEmpty()
     from two in second.DefaultIfEmpty()
     from three in third.DefaultIfEmpty()
     select String.Join(" ", NotEmpty(one, two, three));
```

Note: I have used `String.Join` to join items which are not null or empty and method to select non-empty items to be joined (you can inline this code if you don't want to have a separate method):

```
private static IEnumerable<string> NotEmpty(params string[] items)
{
    return items.Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
}
```

Output for sample above is

```
[ "a c", "a", "a d", "b c", "b", "b d" ]
```

For two collections and foreach loops (though I would prefere LINQ as above):

```
IEnumerable<string> first = new[] { "a", "b" };
IEnumerable<string> second = new string[0];

foreach(var one in first.DefaultIfEmpty())
{
     foreach(var two in second.DefaultIfEmpty())
        yield return $"{one} {two}".Trim(); // with two items simple Trim() can be used
}
```

Output:

```
[ "a", "b" ]
```

Comment: @doremifasolasido what do you mean by that? If you'll make second collection empty, then result will be exactly the same.

Comment: Ah, beautiful. Basically, the same answer as @doremifasolasido but with a framework supplied method instead of coding the empty arrays. Both of your answers are what I am looking for.

Comment: Trim() will remove only the start and end extra white spaces ... not the middle ones

Comment: @michaelkoss there is a **significant** difference - `Any()` will start enumeration. In simplest way it will just create enumerator object and try to get first item. But if your strings come from slow resource like file or database, then it will open file or run database query one more time

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, I'm not too familiar with the implementation of `DefaultIfEmpty()`, but wouldn't it have to do the same to determine if the `IEnumerable` were empty or not?

Comment: @michaelkoss no, it will be called once in `foreach` loop or in linq `from` statement. Then on first iteration if no items found, default will be returned. Otherwise simply items will be returned

Answer (score 3):

You can simply check that first enumerable is not empty:

```
IEnumerable<string> first = new [] {"a", "b"};
IEnumerable<string> second = new [] {"c", "d"};

var firstList = first.ToList();

if (!firstList.Any()) {
    return second;
}

foreach (string one in firstList)
{
   foreach (string two in second)
   {
      yield return string.Format("{0} {1}", one, two);
   }
}
```

To eliminate double `IEnumerable` evaluation in positive cases just convert first enumerable to list

Comment: That's the correct solution - the OP wants a special case if a list is empty, so the correct solution is to check for the special condition. Why is this downvoted?

Comment: Why the `ToList` call?

Comment: In case when `first` is not empty, there will be two `IEnumerable` evaluations without list conversion

Comment: Probably should also check if the second is empty and return the first in that case, but that's up to the OP's requirements.

Comment: Instead of calling ToList you can check if first implements IList. Not sure materializing IEnumerable of unknown size is such a good idea, given that Any will lookup at most 1 item (in case first does not implement IList). Actually I guess Any will do that check for you anyway.

Comment: @Evk he added it because of my earlier (now deleted) comment that doing both `Any()` and the foreach causes double evaluation of the `IEnumerable`. If the `IEnumerable` is backed by function with a `yield return` it will cause multiple executions of that function.

Answer (score 1):

Your current approach should work until any of the collections is empty. If this is the case you need some check in front:

```
if(!first.Any())
    foreach(var e in second) yield return e;
else if(!second.Any())
    foreach(var e in first) yield return e;

foreach (string one in first)
{
   foreach (string two in second)
   {
      yield return string.Format("{0} {1}", one, two);
   }
}
```

However you should consider making an immediate execution using `ToList` in front to avoid multiple iterations of the same collection.

Comment: Be careful, this results in a double evaluation of the IEnumerable you call `.Any()` on..

Comment: Yes, my actual code uses a .ToList() on the second to avoid multiple iterations over the IEnumerable. If I have to use .Any(), I will include the .ToList() on the first as well.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're output for case :

```
IEnumerable<string> first = new string[0];
IEnumerable<string> second = new [] {"c", "d"};
```

would be :

```
c
d
```

This would work :

```
var query = from x in first.Any() ? first : new [] { "" }
            from y in second.Any() ? second : new[] { "" }
            select x + y;
```

> Less code , easier to maintain and debug !

**Edit :** If you have any other IEnumerable is just 1 extra line per IEnumerable ( includes the check )

```
var query = from x in first.Any() ? first : new [] { "" }
            from y in second.Any() ? second : new[] { "" }
            from z in third.Any() ? third : new[] { "" }
            select x + y + z;
```

**Edit 2** : you can just add the spaces at the end :

```
select (x + y + z).Aggregate(string.Empty, (c, i) => c + i + ' ');
```

Comment: So far, this is the closest answer to what I am looking for.

Comment: @michaelkoss this will not have whitespaces between items in output. Is it OK for you?

Comment: Close, but if I understood the OP correctly, there is a subtle difference: If the first enumerable is `{""}`, the result should be `{" c", " d"}`. If it is empty, the result should be `{"c", "d"}`.

Comment: .Aggregate(string.Empty, (c, i) => c + i + ' '); will just add the spaces at the end of the logic

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, I understand this would not have the whitespace, I can selectively add/remove it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than a couple lists, you can setup a recursive iterator. You'll want to be mindful of the stack, and I think the string concatenation is less than ideal, and passing lists of lists is rather clunky, but this should get you started.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace en
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // three sample lists, for demonstration purposes.
            var a = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };
            var b = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" };
            var c = new List<string>() { "i", "ii", "iii" };

            // the function needs everything in one argument, so create a list of the lists.
            var lists = new List<List<string>>() { a, b, c };

            var en = DoStuff(lists).GetEnumerator();

            while (en.MoveNext())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(en.Current);
            }
        }

        // This is the internal function. I only made it private because the "prefix" variable
        // is mostly for internal use, but there might be a use case for exposing that ...
        private static IEnumerable<String> DoStuffRecursive(IEnumerable<String> prefix, IEnumerable<IEnumerable<String>> lists)
        {
            // start with a sanity check
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(null, lists) || lists.Count() == 0)
            {
                yield return String.Empty;
            }

            // Figure out how far along iteration is
            var len = lists.Count();

            // down to one list. This is the exit point of the recursive function.
            if (len == 1)
            {
                // Grab the final list from the parameter and iterate over the values.
                // Create the final string to be returned here.
                var currentList = lists.First();
                foreach (var item in currentList)
                {
                    var result = prefix.ToList();
                    result.Add(item);

                    yield return String.Join(" ", result);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Split the parameter. Take the first list from the parameter and 
                // separate it from the remaining lists. Those will be handled 
                // in deeper calls.
                var currentList = lists.First();
                var remainingLists = lists.Skip(1);

                foreach (var item in currentList)
                {
                    var iterationPrefix = prefix.ToList();
                    iterationPrefix.Add(item);

                    // here's where the magic happens. You can't return a recursive function
                    // call, but you can return the results from a recursive function call.
                    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/2055944/1462295
                    foreach (var x in DoStuffRecursive(iterationPrefix, remainingLists))
                    {
                        yield return x;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // public function. Only difference from the private function is the prefix is implied.
        public static IEnumerable<String> DoStuff(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<String>> lists)
        {
            return DoStuffRecursive(new List<String>(), lists);
        }
    }
}
```

console output:

```
a 1 i
a 1 ii
a 1 iii
a 2 i
a 2 ii
a 2 iii
a 3 i
a 3 ii
a 3 iii
b 1 i
b 1 ii
b 1 iii
b 2 i
b 2 ii
b 2 iii
b 3 i
b 3 ii
b 3 iii
c 1 i
c 1 ii
c 1 iii
c 2 i
c 2 ii
c 2 iii
c 3 i
c 3 ii
c 3 iii
```