# How to get all the shapes in powerpoint presentation? (I need in OpenXml)

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint, office-interop

I need to get all the shapes in active presentation from all slides, including the shapes in grouped items in C#.

I need all shapes returned in List or Array(Shape).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate shapes of a slide via [`Shapes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ff760106%28v%3Doffice.14%29) property. Similarly you can enumerate child shapes via [`GroupItems`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ff761808%28v%3Doffice.14%29) property (only for `msoGroup` shape type). To put that together:

```
public static IEnumerable<Shape> EnumerateShapes(Presentation presentation)
{
    return presentation.Slides.Cast<Slide>().SelectMany(slide =>
        EnumerateShapes(slide.Shapes.Cast<Shape>()));
}

public static IEnumerable<Shape> EnumerateShapes(IEnumerable<Shape> shapes)
{
    foreach (Shape shape in shapes)
    {
        yield return shape;
        if (shape.Type == Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoShapeType.msoGroup)
        {
            foreach (var subShape in EnumerateShapes(shape.GroupItems.Cast<Shape>()))
                yield return subShape;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this kind of recursion comes at its cost and maybe it would be wise to convert the above method to [non-recursive one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30441479).