# recursive function fails to get the expected result in c#

Tags: c#, recursion

I have the following classes,

**User:**

```cs
public class User:Domain
    {
        [Sortable]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Sortable]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [NestedSortable]
        public Profile Profile { get; set; }
    }
```

**Profile:**

```cs
public class Profile : Domain
    {
        [Sortable]
        public string BrandName { get; set; }

        [NestedSortable]
        public Client Client { get; set; }

        [NestedSortable]
        public ProfileContact ProfileContact { get; set; }
    }
```

**Client:**

```cs
public class Client : Domain
    {
        [Sortable]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

**Profile Contact:**

```cs
public class ProfileContact : Domain
    {
        [Sortable]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm writing a recursive function to get all the properties decorated with `[Sortable]` attribute. This works well when I have a single `[NestedSortableProperty]` but fails when I have more than one.

Here is my recursive function:

```cs
private static IEnumerable<SortTerm> GetTermsFromModel(
            Type parentSortClass,
            List<SortTerm> sortTerms,
            string parentsName = null,
            bool hasNavigation = false)
        {
            if (sortTerms is null)
            {
                sortTerms = new List<SortTerm>();
            }

            sortTerms.AddRange(parentSortClass.GetTypeInfo()
                       .DeclaredProperties
                       .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes<SortableAttribute>().Any())
                       .Select(p => new SortTerm
                       {
                           ParentName = parentSortClass.Name,
                           Name = hasNavigation ? $"{parentsName}.{p.Name}" : p.Name,
                           EntityName = p.GetCustomAttribute<SortableAttribute>().EntityProperty,
                           Default = p.GetCustomAttribute<SortableAttribute>().Default,
                           HasNavigation = hasNavigation
                       }));

            var complexSortProperties = parentSortClass.GetTypeInfo()
                       .DeclaredProperties
                       .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes<NestedSortableAttribute>().Any());

            if (complexSortProperties.Any())
            {
                foreach (var parentProperty in complexSortProperties)
                {
                    var parentType = parentProperty.PropertyType;

                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parentsName))
                    {
                        parentsName = parentType.Name;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        parentsName += $".{parentType.Name}";
                    }

                    return GetTermsFromModel(parentType, sortTerms, parentsName, true);
                }
            }

            return sortTerms;
        }
```

<s>this happens because of the return statement inside the `foreach` loop. How to rewrite this? with this example I need to get a list of `FirstName`,`LastName`,`BrandName`,`Name` and `Email`. But I'm getting only the first four properties except `Email`.</s>

Now that the above issue is resolved by removing the return statement as posted in my own answer below and also following @Dialecticus comments to use `yield return`. so I strike and updated the question.

Now I'm running into another issue. The parent class name is wrongly assigned if a class has multiple `[NestedSortable]` properties.

This method is called first time with `User` class like `var declaredTerms = GetTermsFromModel(typeof(User), null);`

Example,

After the first call, the `parentsName` parameter will be null and `[Sortable]` properties in `User` class don't have any effect.

Now for the `[NestedSortable]` `Profile` property in `User` class, the `parentsName` will be `Profile` and so the `[Sortable]` properties in `Profile` class will have `Name` as `Profile.BrandName` and so on.

`Name` property in final list to be as follows,

**Expected Output:**

FirstName, LastName, Profile.BrandName, Profile.Client.Name, Profile.ProfileContact.Email

**But Actual Output:**

FirstName, LastName, Profile.BrandName, Profile.Client.Name, Profile.Client.ProfileContact.Email

Please assist on how to fix this.

Thanks,

Abdul

Comment: `sortTerms` variable should not be the input parameter of the method. It should in fact be the output of the method. Also, the method returns `IEnumerable` but there is no `yield return` anywhere. See this to find out how to `yield return` from recursive function: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2055927/395718

Comment: @Dialecticus what is yield and why this change needs to be done? Please assist

Comment: When learning new stuff is required It's easier for me to redirect you to google. Search for c# yield return. This is the way the `IEnumerable` works.

Comment: And why `sortTerms` should not be input?

Comment: Because its nature is to be output. It is needed just to be returned to the caller. It is not needed internally.

Comment: Instead of `sortTerms.AddRange(...)` there should be `foreach (var x in ...) yield return x;`. And calling `GetTermsFromModel` recursively should also be in the loop, `foreach (var x in GetTermsFromModel(...)) yield return x;`

Comment: @Dialecticus Thanks for your assistance and guidance. Kudos to you. You earned my respect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196318/discussion-between-abdul-rahman-and-dialecticus).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some debugging, I removed the return statement inside `foreach` loop and that fixed the first issue.

changed from,

```cs
return GetTermsFromModel(parentType, sortTerms, parentsName, true);
```

to,

```cs
GetTermsFromModel(parentType, sortTerms, parentsName, true);
```

Then as per @Dialecticus comments removed passing `sortTerms` as input parameter and removed the parameter inside the code and changed `sortTerms.AddRange(...)` to `yield return`.

changed from,

```cs
sortTerms.AddRange(parentSortClass.GetTypeInfo()
                       .DeclaredProperties
                       .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes<SortableAttribute>().Any())
                       .Select(p => new SortTerm
                       {
                           ParentName = parentSortClass.Name,
                           Name = hasNavigation ? $"{parentsName}.{p.Name}" : p.Name,
                           EntityName = p.GetCustomAttribute<SortableAttribute>().EntityProperty,
                           Default = p.GetCustomAttribute<SortableAttribute>().Default,
                           HasNavigation = hasNavigation
                       }));
```

to,

```cs
foreach (var p in properties)
            {
                yield return new SortTerm
                {
                    ParentName = parentSortClass.Name,
                    Name = hasNavigation ? $"{parentsName}.{p.Name}" : p.Name,
                    EntityName = p.GetCustomAttribute<SortableAttribute>().EntityProperty,
                    Default = p.GetCustomAttribute<SortableAttribute>().Default,
                    HasNavigation = hasNavigation
                };
            }
```

also for complex properties, changed from,

```cs
GetTermsFromModel(parentType, sortTerms, parentsName, true);
```

to,

```cs
var complexProperties = GetTermsFromModel(parentType, parentsName, true);

                    foreach (var complexProperty in complexProperties)
                    {
                        yield return complexProperty;
                    }
```

And for the final issue I'm facing with the name, adding the below code after the inner `foreach` loop fixed it,

```cs
parentsName = parentsName.Replace($".{parentType.Name}", string.Empty);
```

So here is the complete updated working code:

```cs
private static IEnumerable<SortTerm> GetTermsFromModel(
            Type parentSortClass,
            string parentsName = null,
            bool hasNavigation = false)
        {
            var properties = parentSortClass.GetTypeInfo()
                       .DeclaredProperties
                       .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes<SortableAttribute>().Any());

            foreach (var p in properties)
            {
                yield return new SortTerm
                {
                    ParentName = parentSortClass.Name,
                    Name = hasNavigation ? $"{parentsName}.{p.Name}" : p.Name,
                    EntityName = p.GetCustomAttribute<SortableAttribute>().EntityProperty,
                    Default = p.GetCustomAttribute<SortableAttribute>().Default,
                    HasNavigation = hasNavigation
                };
            }

            var complexSortProperties = parentSortClass.GetTypeInfo()
                       .DeclaredProperties
                       .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes<NestedSortableAttribute>().Any());

            if (complexSortProperties.Any())
            {
                foreach (var parentProperty in complexSortProperties)
                {
                    var parentType = parentProperty.PropertyType;

                    //if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parentsName))
                    //{
                    //    parentsName = parentType.Name;
                    //}
                    //else
                    //{
                    //    parentsName += $".{parentType.Name}";
                    //}

                    var complexProperties = GetTermsFromModel(parentType, string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parentsName) ? parentType.Name : $"{parentsName}.{parentType.Name}", true);

                    foreach (var complexProperty in complexProperties)
                    {
                        yield return complexProperty;
                    }

                    //parentsName = parentsName.Replace($".{parentType.Name}", string.Empty);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: There is a potential bug where the last `Replace` would remove more than just the last `parentType.Name` (if there is more than one such token substring in the string). I would suggest that you don't manipulate `parentsName`, but pass the appended string directly to recurse call, `GetTermsFromModel(parentType, parentsName + $".{parentType.Name}", true)`

Comment: good catch. but If i pass directly then for the first time when it is null then it will be `.User` and this will have unexpected output right?

Comment: Right, you can use conditional operator for that case, `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parentsName) ? parentType.Name : $"{parentsName}.{parentType.Name}"`

Comment: updated the answer as per your comments. Many thanks for your guidance. <3