# Depth First Recursion with IAsyncEnumerable

Tags: c#, recursion, .net-core, generator, .net-core-3.0

The topic of recursion with an `IEnumerable` was covered in [this 2010 SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055927/ienumerable-and-recursion-using-yield-return).  I'm curious how the story has changed with the advent of `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` in .Net Core 3.X?  Specifically:

1. Should I still be concerned about the resource cost of creating iterators recursively, for deep trees, as Jon Skeet warned?
2. In that same SO post, someone provided a "generic non-recursive extension method" to achieve depth first iteration without recursion.  If that same approach should be used today, what does an updated version of that `RecursiveSelect()` extension look like for `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`?

My interest is performing a depth first search of a (remote) file system, where each iteration causes one of the remote files to be downloaded locally.  To that end, I intend to create an asynchronous "generator" (an iterator whose length is unknown) which I can iterate with `await foreach`.

As a test case, I'm first simply trying to do a depth-first-search of a local directory...copying the files I find to some other arbitrary folder.

I want to be sure I'm using `IAsyncEnumerable` effectively.

Note: Even if creating vast numbers of `IAsyncEnumerable` iterators is not expensive for a deep tree, it still makes sense to use the non-recursive approach because the non-recursive approach is probably capable of "check-pointing" its progress and can "resume" if something caused the application to crash.  I'm not sure the same could be done for the recursive approach.

Answer (score 2):

The same considerations/solutions should apply to `IAsyncEnumerable`, you can check at [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0ATEBqAPgAQAYACfARhQG4BYAKCNLIFYb6BmUgJmIGFiBvOsWGMkpABzEAkgEEAzgE8AdmACiSgK4BbGFACGwADYwAPAEslAFwB8xGeoAUASiEjBtEZ+IAzaMQcWlsRmxAC8xGSUwcQm4WSEUWbY2C4eXsLu6en4AJykSAB0ACIwhnoKDvGEhE6UAPR1AMpmWhplljDEAO56ZpYWAOY+fhh6lnrElhDEkDqTABZQEBoD8wXErlki5GSkAOzBrFsAvpvEp7THQA=) - state machine and iterators created per method invocation with extra code for asynchronous handling (compare to the "simple" [IEnumerable with yield return](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0ATEBqAPgAQAYACfARhQG4BYAKHwGZSAmYgYWIG87jfSyk/BgB4AlgDsALgD5iAUXEAKAJQ8+3Wny3EAZtGKKJk4qOIBeYmUoniwi2ULXR2bKs3beGjx/JlSAdhMadw8AXzVecNpQoA)):

This method:

```
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<int> AEn()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);//Simulate waiting for data to come through. 
        yield return i;
    }
}
```

Is translated by compiler to:

```
[AsyncIteratorStateMachine(typeof(<AEn>d__0))]
public static IAsyncEnumerable<int> AEn()
{
    return new <AEn>d__0(-2);
}
```

Where `<AEn>d__0` is compiler generated implementation of `IAsyncEnumerable`.

So you should use the stack implementation for your depth-first-search.