# Ref int question in C#

Tags: c#, .net, pass-by-reference

Simply put, I am using a while loop to repeat a method, and each time the method is run the int "i" will increase by 1. Although I am having trouble calling the "NumberUp" method. error output is below.

**Main method:**

```
while (true)
{
    NumberUp(0);
}
```

**NumberUp Method:**

```
public static void NumberUp(ref int i)
{
    i++;
    System.Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

I keep getting the following error:

> > The best overloaded method match for 'ConsoleApplication2.Program.NumberUp(ref int)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Are you trying to increment the value of the literal `0`? It doesn't maker sense to pass a literal as a `ref`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use the 'ref' keyword when passing an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186891/why-use-the-ref-keyword-when-passing-an-object)

Comment: @JimFell This is a separate issue.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To call a method that takes a `ref` parameter, you need to pass a variable, and use the `ref` keyword:

```
int x = 0;
NumberUp(ref x);
//x is now 1
```

This passes a *reference* to the `x` variable, allowing the `NumberUp` method to put a new value into the variable.

Answer (score 2):

Ref is used to pass a variable as a reference. But you are not passing a variable, you are passing a value.

```
 int number = 0;
 while (true)
 {
      NumberUp(ref number );
 }
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

A ref parameter needs to be passed by ref and needs a variable:

```
int i = 0;
while (true)
{
    NumberUp(ref i);
}
```

Comment: Now that would be daft! Declare `i` outside the loop!

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass `0` as a reference in a variable containing `0`, for instance:

```
int i = 0;
NumberUp(ref i);
```

Read here at MSDN for more information on the *[ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)* keyword.

Comment: That's poorly phrased.  You need to pass a reference to a variable containing `0`.

Answer (score -1):

[ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx)

```
NumberUp(ref number );
```