# What does the keyword ref mean in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Below is my code please explain what is ref cboListType.

```
Lists.LoadListTypes(ref cboListType);

public static void LoadListTypes(ref DropDownList dropDown)
{
    if (!Util.IsCached(LIST_TYPES))
    {
        Util.InsertIntoCache(LIST_TYPES, DataAccess.ListListTypes());
    }

    dropDown.DataSource = (DataTable)Util.GetFromCache(LIST_TYPES);
    dropDown.DataBind();
    dropDown.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", ""));
}
```

Comment: If I say 'a reference to a DropDownList object', would that help you?

Comment: Are you trying to understand the ref keyword, what a drop down list is, or possibly something else?

Comment: It's your code and you don't know what it does?

Comment: @Edwin de Koning: it's not "a reference to a DropDownList object", it's a reference to reference to a DropDownList object. Without `ref`, you "pass object using reference to this object", with `ref`, you "pass reference to reference to this object".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why use ref keyword when passing an Object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186891/why-use-ref-keyword-when-passing-an-object)

Answer (score 3):

The [`ref` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) indicates that a parameter is passed by reference.

In the code you posted, it's perfectly useless, because the method doesn't change the value of the parameter (changing properties of the parameter doesn't require passing it by reference, at least not if it is a reference type)

Answer (score 2):

`ref` keyword means "pass by reference". When you pass some `DropDownList` reference to `LoadListTypes()` this reference may be changed. So after this call, the reference you've passed could refer to absolutely another object.

```
void func(ref MyClass mc)
{
  mc = new MyClass(2);
}

MyClass mc = new MyClass(1);
MyClass mc2 = mc;
// mc and mc2 are the same
func(ref mc);
// mc and mc2 may differ
```

Answer (score 1):

The C# ref keyword causes a method to refer to the same variable that was passed into the method.  Any changes made to that variable are reflected in that variable when control is passed back.

Comment: Thank you Josh for your reply.I have one more doubt when we need to use this ref key word?

Comment: It's mostly used to change value types such a struct, int, char, etc... within a method rather than returning a value.  If you have an object that is not a struct (i.e. a class), then passing by ref is done implicitly because the object is already a reference type, so any changes made within the method will affect that object.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is a [System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0ybx34e.aspx), and it almost certainly should not be declared ref.

Answer (score 0):

*ref* means parameter is passed by reference, not by value. [More detailed info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

> Refer to the same DropDownList that was passed into the method.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> The ref method parameter keyword on a method parameter causes a method
>   to refer to the same variable that was passed into the method. Any
>   changes made to the parameter in the method will be reflected in that
>   variable when control passes back to the calling method.

Comment: Thank you Squid  for your reply.

Comment: Can you please explain me with example?

Comment: I think to understand that the 'ref' keyword is used its to allow the method to make lasting changes to the object. You use the ref keyword to make lasting changes to value type parameters. If you haven't learned the difference between value types and reference types I'd have a look at this following link. Good luck! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: *Normally when a value type is passed to a method a copy of the original value-type is created and passed to the method, not the original value. This means that any changes made by the method will not persist after the method is done calling.