# Passing object (pass by reference) to a function does not persist changes

Tags: c#, .net

Consider following code, I am trying to implement custom link list.

Expected Output : Start-->123-->11-->NULL
Actual Output : Start-->11-->NULL

```
class MyLinkList
    {
        public object data { get; set; }

        public MyLinkList Next { get; set; }
    }

  public static void PrintLinkList(MyLinkList start)
        {
            Console.Write("Start-->");
            while (start != null)
            {
                Console.Write(start.data + "-->");
                start = start.Next;
            }
            Console.Write("NULL");
        }

  public static void AddNodeStart( MyLinkList start, object data)
        {
            MyLinkList newNode = new MyLinkList();
            newNode.data = data;
            newNode.Next = start;

            start = newNode;
        }

 public static void Main()
        {

            MyLinkList n = new MyLinkList() { data = 11, Next = null };

            AddNodeStart( n,123);

            PrintLinkList(n);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

The problem is even though node is added to the list in the AddToStart function, its value is not persisted when control come back to main function.

Object is passed by reference then why its value is not getting persisted. if I use 'ref' word then I get the expected result.

Atul sureka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go the answer from [Why use the 'ref' keyword when passing an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186891/why-use-ref-keyword-when-passing-an-object?rq=1).

Value is not getting persisted because I am creating a new object in AddNodeStart. If I modify the existing object in the function then the changes would be persisted.

Answer (score 3):

Add `ref` to your method declaration like so:

```
public static void AddNodeStart(ref MyLinkList start, object data)
```

then call it

```
AddNodeStart(ref n,123);
```

and it should work.

If you don't, then `start` is just a variable inside AddNodeStart method - assigning values to it will not change reference stored in `n`.

That said it is rather a bad taste to do this. Instead consider returning the new node from your add method.

```
public static MyLinkList AddNodeStart(MyLinkList start, object data)
{
    MyLinkList newNode = new MyLinkList();
    newNode.data = data;
    newNode.Next = start;
    return newNode;
}
```

then call it this way:

```
n = AddNodeStart(n,123);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the reference in C# (also in Java) is passed **by value**. The actually reference used in the method is the copy of the reference value passed in. (The object being referred is not copied)

Another example is you can't swap 2 objects by passing the references into a method. Since all references are passed by value, what you actually swap is the **values** of the **copied** references.