# Use any UIViewController subclass as generic parameter for method

Tags: c#, ios, generics, uiviewcontroller, xamarin

I don't want to repeat code and therefore I thought I use a method which does that for me. What I want to do is to use any `UIViewController` subclass as parameter (by reference). I tried something like this

```
private void removeViewController<T>(ref object viewController){
    if (viewController != null) {
        viewController = (T)Convert.ChangeType (viewController, typeof(T));
        viewController.RemoveFromParentViewController ();
        viewController.Dispose ();
        viewController = null;
    }
}
```

and call it in this way

```
removeFromContainer<CustomViewController> (ref customViewController);
```

but I can't compile. I get

> Cannot convert 'ref CustomViewController' expression to type 'ref object'

on calling *removeFromContainer* and

> Type 'object' does not contain a definition for 'RemoveFromParentViewController' and no extension method 'RemoveFromParentViewController' of type 'object' could be found.

in my method (*removeFromContainer*).

How can I solve that? What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast your `object` as type `UIViewController` and use it without generics.

```
private void removeViewController(object objviewController)
{
    var viewController = viewController as UIViewController
    if (viewController  != null) 
    {      
        viewController.RemoveFromParentViewController();
        viewController.Dispose ();
    }
}
```

Comment: I still get *Cannot convert 'ref CustomViewController' expression to type 'ref object'* on `removeFromContainer (ref customViewController);`

Comment: I dont think it would be necessary, you can remove it from the parentview without using `ref`

Comment: Can I remove the `ref` because it is already passed by reference?

Comment: Yes. you are right. Please see this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/186891/1155650) if interested.