# Why is this false if statement running? (C#)

Tags: c#, if-statement, logical-operators

See the link:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NH6bX.png

Notice the Autos window at the bottom shows that toParse = "". However toParse != "" evaluates as true anyway, causing the application to crash.

Here's the full method:

```
public void parseString(string toParse)
    {
        while (toParse != "")
        {
            string nextLine = readLine(ref toParse);

            if (nextLine.IndexOf("//") == 0)
            {
                comments.Add(nextLine);
                continue;
            }

            if (nextLine.IndexOf(".") == 0)
            {
                string[] declarationParts = nextLine.Split(' ');
                string declarationString = declarationParts[0].Substring(1, declarationParts[0].Length - 1);
                declarationString = char.ToUpper(declarationString[0]) + declarationString.Substring(1);
                DirectiveEnum type = (DirectiveEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(DirectiveEnum), declarationString);
                string[] attributes = declarationParts.Skip(1).ToArray();
                MSILNode newNode = new MSILNode(type);
                newNode.addAttributes(attributes);
                toParse = toParse.Trim();
                if (toParse != "")
                {
                    while (toParse[0] != '{' && toParse[0] != '.' && toParse.IndexOf("//") != 0)
                    {
                        nextLine = readLine(ref toParse);
                        attributes = nextLine.Split(' ');
                        newNode.addAttributes(attributes);
                    }

                    if (toParse[0] == '{')
                    {
                        readLine(ref toParse);
                        string inside = separate(ref toParse, "}");

                        newNode.parseString(inside);
                    }
                }
                subNodes.Add(newNode);
                continue;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(nextLine);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What was the value of toParse?

Comment: What's the length of `toParse`?

Comment: See op: toParse = ""

Comment: Length is 0. If I use toParse.Length != 0, the same issue occurs.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to see everything that's happening during the debugging session when only given this one snapshot.  However, since `toParse` is passed by reference to the function `readline()` (line 57), it's value can be changed in the body of that function.

From the PNG image provided in the original question:

```
53 if (toParse != "")
54 {
55     while (toParse[0] != '{' && toParse[0] != '.' && toParse.IndexOf("//") != 0)
56     {
57         nextLine = readLine(ref toParse);
58         ...
```

At line 53, `toParse` is not empty.  Then, during one of the iterations of the `while` loop, it is updated to an empty value.  This would cause any accesses to array indices (i.e. `toParse[0]` in the while condition) to throw an exception.

For more information on the `ref` keyword in C#, see [this StackOverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186891/why-use-the-ref-keyword-when-passing-an-object) or [this official Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx).

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In the image, this line `newNode.parseString(inside)` is highlighted meaning that it's in the Callstack and was called before crashing. This line is probably mutating toParse to be "".

Comment: I've modified my OP to show the entire method. The first thing I check when calling parseString() is whether or not the passed string is == "".