# The best overloaded method match ... has some invalid arguments [byref / byval]

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb6

I am calling a dll ( written in vb6 ) from asp.net application . I am calling the following function of dll :

```
Public Function FamIdentify_BYTE(strName As String, strDatabaseTemplate As Variant, len_of_data As Long, strIdentifyTemplate As String, strIP As String) As Boolean
```

The following code in C# calls the above function :

```
public Boolean VerifyFinger(String name , String SampleModel, String REMOTE_ADDR)
        {

            try
            {
                Connect();
                OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();  
                string sql = "SELECT FINGER_DATA,DATA_LENGTH,SERIAL_NO FROM FP_BIOMETRIC_DATA WHERE CUST_NO =" + name.Trim();
                command.CommandText = sql;
                OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                bool fingerMatched = false;
                FamServer.FamApp famApp = new FamServer.FamApp();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Object[] values = new object[3];
                    int numColumns = reader.GetValues(values);
                    byte[] fingerData = values[0] as byte[];
                    string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fingerData);

                    int length_of_data =  Convert.ToInt32(values[1]);
                    int serial_no = Convert.ToInt32(values[2]);

                    //                     FamIdentify_BYTE(ref string, ref object, ref int, ref string, ref string)
                    fingerMatched = famApp.FamIdentify_BYTE(name, fingerData, length_of_data, SampleModel, REMOTE_ADDR);

               //     if (fingerMatched)
                       // break;
                }
                famApp.Termination();
               // famApp = null;
                GC.Collect();

                Close();
                return fingerMatched;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<br>" + e.GetBaseException() + "<br>");
                return false;
            }
        }
```

But when I run the application in IIS express , I am getting this error :

```
The best overloaded method match for 'FamServer._FamApp.FamIdentify_BYTE(ref string, ref object, ref int, ref string, ref string)'
 has some invalid arguments ASPNET(1)
```

This is the full error list :

```
F:\ASP.NET Projects\ASPNET\App_Code\Global.asax.cs(180,37): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'FamServer._FamApp.FamIdentify_BYTE(ref string, ref object, ref int, ref string, ref string)' has some invalid arguments
F:\ASP.NET Projects\ASPNET\App_Code\Global.asax.cs(180,61): error CS1620: Argument '1' must be passed with the 'ref' keyword
F:\ASP.NET Projects\ASPNET\App_Code\Global.asax.cs(180,67): error CS1503: Argument '2': cannot convert from 'byte[]' to 'ref object'
F:\ASP.NET Projects\ASPNET\App_Code\Global.asax.cs(180,79): error CS1620: Argument '3' must be passed with the 'ref' keyword
F:\ASP.NET Projects\ASPNET\App_Code\Global.asax.cs(180,95): error CS1620: Argument '4' must be passed with the 'ref' keyword
F:\ASP.NET Projects\ASPNET\App_Code\Global.asax.cs(180,108): error CS1620: Argument '5' must be passed with the 'ref' keyword
```

If I run the above the above application in IIS server , The redirecting time is too much long . I cant understand why this is happening . Please help me .

Comment: the errors for argument 1, 3, 4, 5 is clear: use the 'ref' keyword when calling the function. at the moment I have no idea for the 2nd parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slight gotcha regarding passing parameters mechanism from [MSDN Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/41zywfyc(v=vs.90).aspx):

> In Visual Basic 6.0, if you do not specify ByVal or ByRef for a
>   procedure parameter, the passing mechanism defaults to ByRef. This
>   allows the variable passed into the procedure to be modified in the
>   calling program.

Using explanation above, the DLL library method by default uses pass-by-reference for all input variables, which has different behavior with C#'s default (pass-by-value instead). Hence, `ref` keyword is mandatory for every passed variables inside method call like this:

```
fingerMatched = famApp.FamIdentify_BYTE(ref name, ref fingerData, ref length_of_data, ref SampleModel, ref REMOTE_ADDR);
```

At this point, it seems working fine but still has second issue which contains invalid cast from a byte array to `object` (`Variant` in VB 6) during passing input parameters. You must convert that byte array to `object` first:

```
byte[] fingerData = values[0] as byte[];

// Variant in VB 6 translated as Object into C#
// Therefore, a conversion to Object type is required
object fingerObject = fingerData;
```

Then, the method call above should be changed to this:

```
fingerMatched = famApp.FamIdentify_BYTE(ref name, ref fingerObject, ref length_of_data, ref SampleModel, ref REMOTE_ADDR);
```

NB: You can't call a method with reference parameters to types other than **exactly** specified parameter type, and the `ref` parameter(s) must be contain any assignable value(s).

Related references:

[Passing Objects By Reference or Value in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708632/passing-objects-by-reference-or-value-in-c-sharp)

[Why use the 'ref' keyword when passing an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186891/why-use-the-ref-keyword-when-passing-an-object)

[Passing Parameters (MSDN Library)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx)

[Cannot convert from 'ref byte[]' to 'ref object'](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/643808/cannot-convert-from-ref-byte-to-ref-object)