# Getting Unexpected value of an object

Tags: c#

Please look at the following code-

```
public class Program
{

  public static void Main()
  {
    A ob = new A();
    ob.x = 120;
    ob.Name = "No";
    GO(ob);
    Console.WriteLine(ob.x);
  }

  public static void GO(A obj)
  {
    obj.x = 50;
    obj.Name = "Local";
    obj = null;
  }
}
```

in console It prints the value of x 50. but when I am using ref keyword it is giving null reference exception. My question is if object is reference type it should give null reference exception even if I don't use ref. and if it is not then value of x in console should be 120. I am unable to understand this behavior. Please explain whats happening here when we use ref and when we don't.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass an argument to a method with `ref` keyword, whatever actions you perform inside the method they are reflected back to the actual argument. In method `GO` you are setting the argument as `null`. So object `ob` has value null before `Console.WriteLine`, hence the null reference exception.

Also in the opposite case when you call the method without the `ref` keyword a copy of reference stored in `ob` variable is passed to `obj` parameter of the method. So both `ob` and `obj` which are two different variables in program stack point to same memory location in the heap. That's how you are able to modify value of `x` inside the method. But setting the value of `obj` to `null` doesn't change the value of `ob`. Thus no null reference exception here.

Comment: you are correct but object is passed as a reference even without using ref that's why value of x changed to 50. but object value didn't set to null and console printed 50 not 120. Why??

Comment: Check modified answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I also got a better reference for this-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186891/why-use-the-ref-keyword-when-passing-an-object