# WPF - initialize object with wizard in second Window

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm struggling in WPF application to initialize object with help of a wizard-like window. I've got main application window which is meant to show the contents of a `Plan` object. I want to initialize the `Plan` object in another window which is something like a wizard to help user parametrize `Plan`.

The concept is following:

*MainWindow.xaml.cs*

```
public partial class MainWindow : RibbonWindow
{
    public Plan apActivePlan;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void rbNewPlan_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WndAddEditPlan wndAddPlan = new WndAddEditPlan(ref apActivePlan);
        wndAddPlan.ShowDialog();

        if (wndAddPlan.DialogResult.HasValue && wndAddPlan.DialogResult.Value)
        {
            /* "Create" button clicked in wndAddPlan,
             * so we update the ListView in MainWindow */
            lvPlanRows.ItemsSource = this.apActivePlan.Rows; // this is where the problem occurs - apActivePlan is null despite the fact that it has been initialized by wndAddPlan
        }
    }
```

*WndAddEditPlan.xaml.cs*

```
public partial class WndAddEditPlan : Window
{
    Plan apActivePlan = null;

    public WndAddEditPlan(ref Plan apActivePlan)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.apActivePlan = apActivePlan;
        if(this.apActivePlan == null)
            this.apActivePlan = new Plan();
    }
    private void btnCreatePlan_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = true;
    }
}
```

The user clicks on `NewPlan` button and wizard pops up to create new `Plan`. The user fills up required information and clicks on `CreatePlan` button. The wizard closes but the apActivePlan within MainWindow is not being initialized.

Answer (score 0):

> You don't have to pass `ref` with reference type objects because of they
>   are already references [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186891/why-use-the-ref-keyword-when-passing-an-object)

Another thing

```
this.apActivePlan = new Plan();
```

Here you are assigning memory to a local variable.

```
Plan apActivePlan = null;
```

Not the one you passed in

```
ref Plan apActivePlan
```

both are different memory pointers.

so you are the assigning memory to local reference to WndAddEditPlan and expecting variable of MainWindow to be initialized.

So change this line

```
apActivePlan = new Plan();
```

instead of

```
this.apActivePlan = new Plan();
```

Comment: I have removed the `ref` keyword and adjusted the line to `apActivePlan = new Plan();` but still after returning to MainWindow the apActivePlan member within MainWindow is `null`.

Comment: If, instead of `WndAddEditPlan wndAddPlan = new WndAddEditPlan(ref apActivePlan);`, I define a constructor in WndAddEditPlan to receive reference to MainWindow instead of only the apActivePlan field it starts to work. Maybe there's something with `DataContext` messed up?